# Replacement for MiKTeX's texify in TeX Live

Tags: compiling, texlive, miktex, automation

I used to use the `texify` command in MiKTeX on Windows. 
I would, for example, run a command like:

`texify --pdf --run-viewer file.tex`

which, as I understand it, would produce a pdf, automatically determine how many times latex needed to be run, and open the resulting pdf in a viewer.

I'm now running Ubuntu and have TeX Live installed.

What would be a good equivalent command when running latex on Ubuntu with TeX Live?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get the [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/) package first:
I don't know the command to do the equivalent as I haven't used the package before. From skimming the document it might be this:

```bsh
latexmk -pdf -pv file.tex
```

Comment: Actually that's a full answer.  I would have posted it myself. I took the liberty to format it as it usual on this site, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help. (BTW: Please keep in mind that many users here are from Europe and therefore life in a different timezone.)

Comment: BTW: If you use `-pvc` than the file is continuously recompiled as soon it is changed. This is great but I have some issues under Ubuntu Linux to automatically reload Adobe Reader after each recompilation.

Comment: latemk works with Windows and MiKTeX as well. Put one line into a config-file "$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --interaction nonstopmode --synctex=-1 %O %S'" and you get e.g. synctex working. To open a command window at the 'right' place, install this little helper:"http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp?T1=PT", and with a rightclick on any folder you may open cmd.exe at this place

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice [discussion of `rubber` on the TeX.SE blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/).

Quoting the post, which in turn is quoting the man page for rubber:

> rubber  “is  a wrapper for LaTeX and companion programs. Its purpose
>   is, given a LaTeX source to process, to compile it enough times to 
>   resolve all  references,  possibly  running  satellite programs such
>   as BibTeX, makeindex, Metapost, etc.  to produce appropriate data
>   files.”

Comment: AFAICS, rubber is not available for Windoes; perhaps you could confirm or deny this?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I run Ubuntu, so I'm not sure.