# How can I avoid compiling twice?

Tags: compiling, automation

Sometimes I need to run compile twice (eg when I use `lastpage`). Is there a way to set things so TeX knows that there is need for second run and do it automatically? I use Texmaker.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit<sub>Updated</sub>: I just noticed I slightly misunderstood your question. There are tools that compile the required number of times automatically, e.g. [latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/latexmk/info). <strike>I don't use it though, but there are certainly users who can tell you all about it.</strike> I've been using latexmk for a little while and it works really well <s>(haven't tried it with bibliographies though)</s>, even with `biblatex` and Biber, and the support is great, the author even answers [questions on here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30350/4012).

As for my initial answer below, it might still be of help in that it can eliminate the need of compiling twice.

---

`hyperref` is a package that frequently requires compiling twice . You can avoid this by loading the package `bookmark` *after* `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

Generally, these two should be the last packages you load in your preamble, unless there's a package that specifically asks to be loaded after `hyperref` (see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/4012)).

`bookmark` provides some new possibilities, but if you've been using `hyperref` and you're not really looking for anything new, you can just load `bookmark` -- according to my experience, it won't change anything (besides the number of necessary compilations).

Comment: It's not just about the order you load packages in; ANYTHING at all that involves a reference — `\cite`, `\ref`, page numbers even, all require double compilation, as the correct references are added in a second pass.

Answer (score 13):

You could set up TeXmaker to use `latexmk` to compile. `latexmk` is a Perl script that you can set up to automatically run `pdflatex` (or other compilers), `bibtex` and/or `makeindex` if necessary.

As a very simple, example you could go to Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Quick Build, and set up a custom Quick Build command such as

```
latexmk -pdf %.tex
```

When running Quick Build, this will run `pdflatex` on the file as many times as necessary. The `%` is TeXmaker's way of representing the filename of the current file (without extension).

See the `latexmk` manual (`texdoc latexmk` in a terminal) for all the possible options.

---

There are other similar options, such as `texify` in MikTeX, [mentioned by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30361/586), and [Rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber). Paulo Cereda wrote a blog post about Rubber, and there was a question concerning the difference between this and `latexmk`.

- Blog post: [Building documents with Rubber](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/12/building-documents-with-rubber/)
- Question: [What are the differences between latexmk and rubber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37154/what-are-the-differences-between-latexmk-and-rubber)

Comment: Can be `latexmk` used with `-shell-escape` option of `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Ichibann Yes. The following is copied directly from page seven of the manual: `latex -pdf -pdflatex=’pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S’ foo.tex`  Edit: I suppose the first word should really be `latexmk`, not just `latex`.

Comment: It should indeed be `latexmk`. If you have a slightly older version of latexmk, you can also use the -e option to execute some Perl code that sets the option: `latexmk -pdf -e '$pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S"' foo.tex`.

Answer (score 6):

With respect to [Seamus' recent blog post on overkill being a good thing](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/overkill-is-a-good-thing/), here's another approach.

The MiKTeX distribution includes [`texify`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html) (and `pdftexify`). These are different from the standard counterparts `latex` (->`dvips`) and `pdflatex` routines since they automatically recompile a document if needed.

Comment: Nice, but I can't see a `texify` in *my* TexLive, which is up-to-date with everything 24 hours ago...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: `texify` is only distributed with MiKTeX (see my answer edits). TeX Live should use `latexmk`, I guess. Also see [Replacement for MikTeX's texify in TeX Live](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22343/replacement-for-miktexs-texify-in-tex-live).