# How can I keep a clean document folder with custom .cls, .sty, .bst files in a separate subfolder?

Tags: texmf, build-system, makefile, environment-variables

I am using a Makefile for generating a document from its tex source. The whole project consisting of own input files (`.tex`, `.bib`, `.eps`, ...) and non-pre-installed static input files (`.cls`, `.sty`, `.bst`) is kept under version control (git) for colloborative writing. I try to avoid messing up the main folder and use subdirectories for output and different kinds of input files.
All files which are not available within TeX Live should be in the repository to allow everyone a simple `git clone` and `make` to create the document. My question is: is there any convenient way which allows me to place all `.cls`, `.sty`, `.bst` into a `./texmf` folder with in the document tree:

```
document-folder
├── .git/...
├── graphics/fig1-<...>.eps
├── graphics/fig2-<...>.eps
├── graphics/...
├── output/docname.pdf
├── output/docname.aux
├── output/...
├── texmf/docclass.cls
├── texmf/custom-package.sty
├── texmf/...
├── docname.tex
├── docname.bib
└── Makefile
```

The Makefile looks like this

```
LATEX    := pdflatex
ODIR     := ./output
LATEXOPTS:= --output-dir=$(ODIR)

    $(TEXFILE).pdf: $(TEXFILE).tex $(TEXFILE).bib
         $(LATEX) $(LATEXOPTS) $(TEXFILE).tex
```

Following solution works but as colloborators have to adjust environment variables every time or their `.bashrc` for this project, I am not really happy about it:

```
$ export TEXINPUTS=".:./texmf:~/texmf:$TEXINPUTS"
$ make
```

Changing environment variables within a Makefile is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Note that in your question as well as all the answers, a colon (```:```) is used as path separator. In windows, this does not work, as a semi-colon (```;```) is used instead. Since linux supports semi-colons as well, it seems like a good practice to me to use them everywhere for better portability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can in fact that environment variables inside a Makefile (tested with GNU make only). You need to do the following:

```
export VAR=value without quotes
```

If you reference the previous value of the same variable you need to use the `:=` assignment instead which expands the value immediately. The normal `=` is expanding the value at every use and will lead to an recursive assignment, which `make` detects and reports as an error.
There are no quotes required around the value and using them might cause trouble. 
Also variables must be written as `${VAR}` on the right-hand side, not `$VAR`.

So you can add the following line to your Makefile, at best at the beginning:

```
export TEXINPUTS:=.:./texmf:~/texmf:${TEXINPUTS}
```

Answer (score 23):

I use [`latexmk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) for some document building, and I've wanted something like this for a long time.  Especially when I have document *and* class under version control.

I discovered that you can configure `latexmk` with a local `latexmkrc` file in the document's directory.  `latexmkrc` files are just perl code.

So in this workflow, if the class files are in `./texmf` you can add the following line to a local `latexmkrc`:

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./texmf//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

This works on my Mac, and I assume on any unix machine that uses environment variables this way.  For windows, and indeed for any platform, `latexmk`'s author John Collins has a solution at [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474915/1402) to [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474756/1402).

Comment: Thanks. This is good to know, too. However, at the moment I still use existing Makefiles and my colleagues are not aware of latexmk. I will give latexmk a try at the next occasion. The customization feature via a latexmkrc file sounds like a neat way to deal with user-dependent preferences.

Comment: Could you clarify that latexmkrc doesn't need a preceding dot in its name?

Comment: @einpoklum According to the [manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/support/latexmk/latexmk.txt), it will work with or without the dot.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang this does not seem to work on Windows.

Comment: @Krishna Unfortunately I have no experience with latexmk and Windows.  There is [some documentation](https://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html) by third party users on how to make it work though.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang nah. Unfortunately that help doc is too shallow for this purpose.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang If you are okay with it, please update your answer to point users to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474756/latexmk-is-unable-to-locate-the-paths-to-my-tex-files-after-configuring-texmfinp/474915#474915 for a platform-indepent awesome answer by `latexmk` creator John Collins

Comment: @Krishna: sure thing.  Glad you got an answer!