# TFM or installed font not found with fontawesome5 (on Overleaf v2 with XeLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, xetex, overleaf, fontawesome

### UPDATE

My question relies on the result of compiling the test project I made (which I linked below), which clearly indicates that the fonts are not being found. While having the `fontawesome5` package as part of the TeX distribution used by Overleaf is customer-service related, having this particular problem I described here *is not*. This could happen apart from Overleaf. For instance, if I wanted to use a custom-made package with included fonts, or a CTAN zip of the same sort, in a local, per-project fashion, without installing it to the computer. That's why I consider this question important and not eligible for closing.

Furthermore, I admit the phrase *"I don't think they would respond. Look, if they would, the package would've been added ages ago!"* was totally unfair for the Overleaf team, who have made an excellent work. So I apologize publicly here for those words I said.

---

### UPDATE #2

Unless people with more knowledge and experience about using this website decide other options, and considering the question was indeed answered, I'll leave this question as it is for the record, to show other users <strike>and myself</strike> how to and how *not to* interact with others here.

---

I tried the procedure described [in the answer of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451004/configuring-fontawesome5-on-overleaf) on Overleaf v2 (as the `fontawesome5` package is still missing in there) to no avail.

The small document I made to test this is available [here (read only)](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wmrmtcgstjth).

Let me note though, that the only difference between that question and this one, is I'm using XeLaTeX.

In particular, the two errors related to the package are:

**Error #1.-** `/fontawesome5/tex/fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty`, line 59

```
Font TU/fontawesomefree/solid/n/12=[FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf]:script=latn; at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.59 ...ze_font:nn{\c__fontawesome_kind_tl}{solid}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

**Error #2.-** `/fontawesome5/tex/fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty`, line 60

```
Font TU/fontawesomebrands/regular/n/12=[FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf]:script=latn; at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.60 ...ntawesome_analyze_font:nn{brands}{regular}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

And then, I'm unable to use the package at all, because commands like `\faCircle` aren't recognized.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something for this particular configuration. What would it be?

What do I need to do to make this package work on Overleaf when using XeLaTeX?

Comment: This is a question best answered by the CS of overleaf. They are very quick to respond. Please contact them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this concerns overleaf support.

Comment: @Raaja I don't think they would respond. Look, if they would, the package would've been added ages ago! Besides, the other question I linked was about the same problem with pdfTeX, and there was a solution for it. I really don't see the point on closing this question.

Comment: generally, overleaf `CS`-like questions are off-topic in this site. Since, this question falls under the scope of one such, I voted to close. However, there are some overleaf questions, in which it is a `TeX` related issues and such a class of questions are on-topic in this site, I think.

Comment: @Raaja Please have a look at the question I linked with this one. It's clearly the same problem as I'm having. The difference is that I'm using XeLaTeX and that's diferent from pdfTeX. And for that question there was a solution, so while having the package available on Overleaf is CS-related, this problem is not. For instance: this could happen too if the package wasn't available with TexLive.

Comment: I will try to look into your issue. Atleast give us the script to compile. Because, external links will be dead over-time. And, giving read-only files doesn't help anyone. Because, if I'm to analyse something, I would first want to do it locally :). Here, the community members usually refrain from going to an external link, just so to access it (without knowing what is behind).

Comment: @Raaja Is that really the problem? If it is, it's clearly not because of this being a CS-related question. I can edit the question to avoid that. But there are files involved in it. Would it be sufficient to explain the folder structure and the involved package?

Comment: that was never the problem `;)`. However, if you expect us to help, please provide us with a MWE that clearly reproduces the issue in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

One extra line needs to be added to your `latexmkrc` file to try using the `fontawesome5` package with XeLaTeX:

```
$ENV{'OPENTYPEFONTS'}='./fontawesome5/opentype/:' . $ENV{'OPENTYPEFONTS'};
```

such that the `.otf` files can be found: the lines at [Configuring fontawesome5 on overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451004/configuring-fontawesome5-on-overleaf) are about using `fontawesome5` with pdflatex, so did not include `OPENTYPEFONTS`.

Somehow there's still an error arising from the test project you posted (which has since been purged so no further debugging can be done), but `fontawesome5` and `XeLaTeX` *does* work find in this small test project that I created: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fpcpdkswcrrb

If you're using `fontawesome5` v5.6.3 or later, though, then on Overleaf you'll then get another error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\__fontawesome_glyphindex:n ...D "\str_if_eq:eeTF 
                                              {stop}{#1}{square}{#1}"\sc...
l.8 Something more... \faAddressBook
```

This is because the command `\str_if_eq:eeTF` is not available on the version of TeX Live 2017 used on Overleaf at present. Therefore at present (March 2019), `fontawesome5` version 5.6.3 and later can't be used with XeLaTeX on Overleaf -- until v5.8.0 that is, that *does* work.

A few other points to clarify:

1. We *do* respond to queries and support requests at `welcome@overleaf.com` and `support@overleaf.com` and we *do* try to respond as quickly as we can :-) though there may be longer delays during weekends... ;-)
2. After opening a project in read-only mode (e.g. https://www.overleaf.com/read/wmrmtcgstjth) you can click on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel, and then "Download - Source" to download a .zip of the source files. Or if you're already signed into your own Overleaf account, you can click on "Copy project" in the menu, to clone it into your own account for an editable copy of your own.

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really glad you explained to me the cause of the problem, and relieved you didn't take my rant personally (because _it was a rant_ for closing the question, shame on me `:(`).

Comment: @liantzetim I'm slightly confused about you saying you'll get an error about `\str_if_eq:eeTF`. If the TeX system used by Overleaf is 'in sync', the `fontspec` version will 'match' the `expl3` version: either both will know about `\str_if_eq:eeTF` or neither will ...

Comment: @JosephWright !!! You're right! This is odd; yesterday I was working on a copy based on the OP's test project and got that error. But seeing your message today, I created a fresh test project myself from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451004/226 and it just all works with XeLaTeX on Overleaf now! Working example here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fpcpdkswcrrb
Unfortunately both the OP and I have purged our test projects from yesterday so I can't look at what went wrong!

Comment: @LianTzeLim Most likely the problem was that you used a newer version of `fontawesome5`: The `\str_if_eq:eeTF` did not appear in fontspec (in fact fontspec isn't used at all), it is used in fontawesome5 itself beginning with version 5.6.3.

Comment: Thanks @MarcelKrüger, that explains a lot! :-)

Comment: I tried out some other icons after copying that project and not all of them seem to work (e.g. `\faRunning` or `\faSnowboarding`). Any idea why that is?

Comment: `\faRunning`, `\faSnowboarding` aren't available in that particular `fontawesome5` version.

Comment: @McAngus If you need the newer icons, you can upload a current version of fontawesome5 to Overleaf. As of version 5.8.0, the problem mentioned above does not exists. You can find an example project with the updated package at https://www.overleaf.com/read/nznjcdhcsfsm