# Raising errors when using fontawesome5 and XeTeX in Debian

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontawesome, debian

I have been trying to compile my CV using the command `xelatex cv.tex` on a Debian-based TeXlive. I normally run it successfully on a MacOS with MacTex using the package `fontawesome5`. However, when I run it on Debian I get the message:

```
(/root/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ignalAlt ,\faDiceD }\regex_const:Nn 
                                                  \c__fontawesome_alt_regex ...
l.58 }
```

which I have no idea what it means. The TeXlive version that I have on Debian is

```
apt-cache policy texlive-xetex
texlive-xetex:
  Installed: 2016.20170123-5
  Candidate: 2016.20170123-5
```

I have installed also the following Debian packages `texlive`, `texlive-bibtex-extra`, `texlive-fonts-extra`, `biber`. I have installed the `fontawesome5` latex package using the command `tlmgr install fontawesome5`.

I also have installed the TeX package `fontawesome` but it did not change the error message.

Does someone know what is wrong with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the TeXlive version for Debian Stretch is old and fontawesome package is new. The problem does not appear in Ubuntu Bionic, for example. This does not quite answer the question, but it provides a workaround.

Comment: You can also install 'vanilla' TeX Live, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu.

Comment: I have read somewhere that there is going to be a new version of fontawsome5 that won't have this problem.

Comment: Found it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479747/tfm-or-installed-font-not-found-with-fontawesome5-on-overleaf-v2-with-xelatex#comment1230938_479759