# Using SourceSerifPro v1.4 package on Overleaf

Tags: fonts, pdftex, overleaf

Overleaf is using SourceSerifPro v1.2 which does not include the italic font.

v1.4 does include italic and is provided as a package on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sourceserifpro/)

Overleaf allows for custom packages to be installed by uploading a .sty file. (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_packages_do_you_support%3F)

I've tried uploading the package from CTAN to overleaf but it's not recognized.

Is there any easy way to use the v1.4 package from CTAN on overleaf so I don't need to resort to building the fonts and using a package such as `fontspec`

(https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F)

Comment: You would also need to upload all the required `.fd`, `.tfm` etc files in the updated version. As there are a lot of such files I'm not sure if it'll be really feasible. If you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, then using `fontspec` would be the easiest solution: you just need to upload the necessary `.ttf` files, and you don't need to build any font files yourself.

Comment: @LianTzeLim They are all uploaded .... currently they are in a directory in the root called `sourceserifpro` which contains subdirectories `tex`, `doc` and `fonts`

Comment: In that case you can add a `latexmkrc` file to your project, similar to this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451049/226 only replace `./fontawesome` with `sourceserifpro/fonts`. Also add `\pdfmapfile{+SourceSerifPro.map}` to your .tex file's preamble. If you can't quite get it to work, it may be best to email support@overleaf.com with your project's URL so that the Overleaf support team (of which I'm a member) can have a closer look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overleaf Tech Support was able to provide a workable solution.

The solution was similar to [the solution described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451049/226) but `sourceserifpro` requires slightly different handling.

Adding the following to `latexmkrc` enables the `T1` encoded fonts.

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./sourceserifpro/tex/:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
$ENV{'TFMFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'TFMFONTS'};
$ENV{'ENCFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'ENCFONTS'};
$ENV{'T1FONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'T1FONTS'};
$ENV{'VFFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'VFFONTS'};
$ENV{'TEXFONTMAPS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'TEXFONTMAPS'};
```

The `$ENV{'VFFONTS'}` line is not included in the previous solution.

Likewise, the following lines should be added to the preamble, changing options as desired.

```
\pdfmapfile{+SourceSerifPro.map}
\usepackage[default,semibold,osf]{sourceserifpro}
```

Unfortunately, ligatures do no work correctly.  Some are render and a box with an x in it, others are rendered totally incorrectly.  For instance, the characters `ff` are being replaced with the ft ligature.

Note, all the above was compiled with `pdfLaTeX`

The ultimate solution was to switch to the `XeLaTex` compiler and to use the OpenType versions of `sourceserifpro`.

In order to enable the OpenType version, the contents of `latexmkrc` was changed to

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./sourceserifpro/tex/:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
$ENV{'TFMFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'TFMFONTS'};
$ENV{'ENCFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'ENCFONTS'};
$ENV{'T1FONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'T1FONTS'};
$ENV{'VFFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'VFFONTS'};
$ENV{'TEXFONTMAPS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'TEXFONTMAPS'};
$ENV{'OPENTYPEFONTS'}='./sourceserifpro/fonts/:' . $ENV{'OPENTYPEFONTS'};
```

Adding the `$ENV{'OPENTYPEFONTS'}` line to the `T1` solution.

The preamble lines from the `T1` solution are still required in the primary `.tex` file.

The downside of switching to `XeLaTeX` is that many of the features of `microtype` are not supported.

My project appears to also work with `LuaLaTeX`.  This means that more, but sadly not all, of the `pdfLaTeX` `microtype` features are working.  In order to get it to compile with `LuaLaTeX` you must delete the aforementioned line

```
\pdfmapfile{+SourceSerifPro.map}
```

as it is not needed with `LuaLaTeX`.