# I want to draw expand-alt icon in my overleaf, but it returns 'was not found' error

Tags: overleaf, fontawesome

I want to draw the icon of[image] in my overleaf page. So I import the `fontawesome5` package and tried `\faExpand*` and `\faIcon{expand-alt}` as `fontawesome5` [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) said, but it did not work. Is there anyone who solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem?

Comment: Welcome again. Have you some errors during the compilation?

Answer (score 2):

The icon `expand-alt` is pretty new in FontAwesome, it has only been added in version 1.12.0. Sadly this version isn't available on Overleaf yet. You could try to update the package manually but given that it is a font package that's a bit complicated. (See [Configuring fontawesome5 on overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451004/configuring-fontawesome5-on-overleaf/451049#451049) if you want to try it). If you can also use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could try updating only the font file:

First switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX by clicking Menu>Compiler and replace pdfLaTeX with LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX). *This might require some changes in your document preamble.*

Then go to https://fontawesome.com/download and select "Free for Desktop". Extract the archive and upload the files from `fontawesome-free-5.12.1-desktop/otfs/`.
The files will have spaces in their names. You have to rename them to delete these spaces. (Just right-click on the file in you Overleaf file list and select Rename)

Now you should have three files named

```
FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf
FontAwesome5Free-Regular-400.otf
FontAwesome5Brands-Regular-400.otf
```

next to your document file. If you recompile your document, the error should be gone.