# How to install elsevier's journal into overleaf

Tags: installing, overleaf, journal

Can someone tell me what to do for creating elsarticle.cls by using the docs provided by following link?

I uploaded all the directory into overleaf but that is it. I couldn't get how to install it.

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle

Comment: Overleaf already has the elsarticle document class, so you don't need to upload the class files. You can go right ahead and write `\documentclass{elsarticle}` in your .tex file. Or start from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-of-elsevier-article-template-with-dummy-text/qfscmwntknmq

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use custom style or other files stored in a specific directory in your Overleaf project with them recognised when you recompile, you can create a file called `latexmkrc` to point to this directory, for example:

```
# Custom locations to include content from 

# Elsevier journal style

$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./tex/latex/elsevier//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

In the above code snippet, './tex/latex/elsevier' is a series of nested folders where I saved the Elsevier style which I downloaded from CTAN.

[image: Example compilation of an Overleaf file using the downloaded elsarticle style class files]

The above is based on directions I found in the Overleaf help library [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I%20have%20a%20lot%20of%20.cls,%20.sty,%20.bst%20files,%20and%20I%20want%20to%20put%20them%20in%20a%20folder%20to%20keep%20my%20project%20uncluttered.%20But%20my%20project%20is%20not%20finding%20them%20to%20compile%20correctly), which in turn was based on a StackExchange post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/how-can-i-keep-a-clean-document-folder-with-custom-cls-sty-bst-files-in-a-s/50847#50847).

There are additional directions found in the elsdoc.pdf file in the elsarticle download from CTAN, [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf).

Regarding the suggestion to use the Overleaf elsarticle template ([here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/example-of-elsevier-article-template-with-dummy-text/qfscmwntknmq)) - this may work, however when I downloaded the elsarticle.cls style following Elsevier directions in January 2021, I noted that the files appeared to have been last updated in 2020, which may be more recent than the linked template which contains a rendered preview dated 2019.  As a new user on this board, my reputation was too low to reply to the comment directly so added this note to my answer here.

Hope this helps!