# Externalize directory and output folder

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, compiling

I have two questions. I'm writing my thesis and I have many files and several TikZ figures I've made. I see that if I use:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
```

my compilation time goes from 49.21s to 3.25s for the full document. The problem is that my working directory gets full of files I don't want to have there, basically what I want is for my directory to have the a structure something like this:

```
Thesis
│   main.pdf (The final pdf)
│   main.tex    
│
└───Chapters
│   
└───Figures (My TikZ files)
│   
└───Junk (The files produced by the compiler)
│   │   *.out
│   │   *.log
│   │   *.md5
│   │   *.pdf (The files produced by external)
│   │   ...
└───Style
│   │   *.sty
```

My questions are:

1. How can I output every file to the Junk directory?
2. Can I grab the style file if it's in another directory? For some reason `\input{Style/style.sty}` didn't work

Comment: For the second question, see [Q50697](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50697). `\input` won't work because the internals of `\usepackage` aren't set up properly.

Comment: The "junk" contains important files needed for the next compilation and other tools, so it is no junk at all and it is normally not a good idea to move  it out of the compilation folder. Use l3build or some makefile instead that copies all files into a build directory, compiles there and then copies the PDF back.

Comment: why call these "junk" ??? having the files is what speeds up the process. It will be possible to configure them to a subdirectory but massively complicates the process (as you need to configure everything to find them)

Comment: Just because I don't like having a ton of files just being there. The answer below by Clara did help but I'm seeing that Ulrike is right, it does complicate things, for some reason when I try to compile everything trough a shell script something breaks and the compilation errors out. I'm happy enough not having  1k+ files in my working directory.

Comment: @AngelPeñaflor When some tikz codes don't need caching, you can use `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`  to mask caching. For example, when you use `orcidlink` package, because `\orcidlink` draws fast, there is no need to cache it. We can avoid caching a large number of orcidlink icons by patching, i.e., `\xpretocmd{\orcidlink}{\tikzexternaldisable}{}{}` and `\xapptocmd{\orcidlink}{\tikzexternalenable}{}{}`. If you use `algpseudocodex` package, you may need `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\tikzexternaldisable}` and \AfterEndEnvironment{algorithmic}{\tikzexternalenable}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage{Style/amsmath}` if `amsmath.sty` is in `Style` folder.

You can use `\tikzexternalize[prefix=Junk/]` to set `external` cache folder, you need to manually create the `Junk` folder before the first time running the LaTeX.

Comment: `\usepackage{Style/amsmath}` is really bad style and latex will warn about the incorrect use.

Comment: Why is it bad use?, I'm not seeing any warning in the log.

Comment: @AngelPeñaflor you should see a warning like ``LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `Style/amsmath', but the package provides `amsmath'.``