# Overleaf can't find the document class when it's in a folder

Tags: overleaf, document-classes, documentclass-writing, folders, cls

I am making my own document class called MyClass in overleaf. I would like to move the cls file into its own folder called Style. How do I change the command `\documentclass[Path=./Style/]{MyClass}` so that it knows where the document class lives?

Comment: why move it? It is far better to place it in the same directory, but you could set an input path in .latexmkrc (or `\documentclass{./Style/MyClass}` would work but is not good practice)

Comment: Please try with `\documentclass{./path/MyClass}`

Comment: Hello there! A tutorial on this is at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_.cls%2C_.sty%2C_.bst_files%2C_and_I_want_to_put_them_in_a_folder_to_keep_my_project_uncluttered._But_my_project_is_not_finding_them_to_compile_correctly which itself is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50847/11002

Answer (score 1):

You can add a file `latexmkrc` containing the line

```
ensure_path('TEXINPUTS', './/:');
```

so all folders are searched

see

https://www.overleaf.com/read/fwygbqshbmjn