# Cross Platform LaTeX Build System

Tags: compiling, windows, automation

I am on Windows 7 Professional (64 bit) and would like to be able to execute one command to completely compile a **PDF** from source .tex files (including all required runs to get the table of contents, bibliography, etc).

I've seen [LatexMake](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/tools/latexmake/) and [Rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber/). When I run LatexMake on Windows using [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) I get the following error:

```
'[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
A subdirectory or file . already exists.
Error occurred while processing: ..
make: *** [.] Error 1
```

I wanted to try Rubber but it has *nix-specific setup instructions. Perhaps somebody can give me some pointers on getting this running on Windows? Searching Google for combinations of `Windows`, `Rubber`, and `LaTeX` has proven ineffective, for obvious reaons (need a latex rubber seal on your windows?). Also, how would I use Rubber to make PDFs? According to the LaTeXMake page generating pdfs with Rubber is an "extra feature."

I would also like to build the same documents using the same solution on *nix systems if at all possible so I can leave the makefiles (or whatever ends up being used) in the source repository.

In the worst-case scenario, I can try using cygwin.

Comment: As you use MiKTeX on Windows, have you looked at texify?

Comment: link to [MiKTeX texify documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texifying.html)

Comment: Is LatexMake the same as [Latexmk](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk)? Latexmk also comes with MiKTeX

Comment: If you really want a unix like environment at Windows instead of using a Windows tool, you may try [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils) or [MSYS](http://mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Comment: If you are happy to write Makefiles, etc., then you simply need an appropriate Makefile for Unix and a `make.bat` batch file on Windows. I'm guessing, however, that you are looking for an automated solution.

Comment: @matth No, LatexMake is *not* the same as latexmk. So I would recommend taking a look at latexmk, which should work fine on Windows (it uses perl).

Comment: There's also [arara](http://cereda.github.com/arara/) which is a Java application so it should work on both windows and *nix

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd go with latexmk -- versions exist for at least the following that I can verify:

- [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=latexmk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=latexmk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). It's not part of their old TeX Live installations, but packaged separately
- TeX Live 2011 on Windows (includes version 4.26)
- MacTeX 2010 (it's in the disabled engines folder for TeXshop by default, but can be easily enabled)

It may be available on other distributions as well. But in any case, I was incredibly happy to see it available by default on TeX Live for Windows. And you're not tied to a particular editor. I'm hoping to deploy a TeXnicCenter profile for our users using latexmk in the next few weeks.

EDIT: one other nice thing with latexmk is that I can automatically have it build a nomenclature or list of symbols for thesis/dissertation purposes. All I have to do is provide a .latexmkrc with the following lines:

```
push @cus_dep_list, "nlo nls 0 nlo2nls"; # nomenclature
sub nlo2nls { system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg"); }
```

which basically says, "if you see a .nlo file, use this makeindex command to convert it into a .nls file".

Comment: On MiKTeX 2.9 latexmk is also included and works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments (but not in an answer yet) I checked out texify. Running the following command does everything I need:

```
texify -p input.tex
```

Thanks, everybody!

Comment: `texify` is not cross-platform as far as I know. It's not included in TeXLive and appears to be MiKTeX only. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22343/9043).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the Texmaker editor.

It is working on Linux, MacOS X and Windows. You can define quick compilation command to do pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex in one sweep, hence producing directly your PDF with bibliography etc... You can add a makeindex pass as well if you have an index.

This is the tool I am using, and I am pretty sure many other people can vouch for other tools providing the same functionnalities.

Still, the very interesting point for Texmaker is that this is a cross-platform editor.

Comment: You can't always point and click on a button. Maybe the OP wants a document to be automatically generated from raw data and built every hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [RTextDoc](http://jwork.org/rtextdoc) LaTeX editor. It is cross platform (since Java)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Rubber: You're right that it's difficult to find information on it because its clever name makes googling difficult. It does install in Cygwin with no trouble. Just download the ZIP or `tar.gz` file for the source from https://launchpad.net/rubber/ then follow the instructions in the README.