# makeglossaries hangs waiting for input on mac

Tags: compiling, glossaries, texshop

I'm very new to Latex so apologies if this is a newbie question. However I have looked around online and can't find an answer.

I'm trying to compile my file in TeXShop (on mac) using the following but I'm not sure how to go about it (using the 'Typeset' button alone is not sufficient). Please can someone help me out?

```
(pdf)latex
makeglossaries
(pdf)latex
(pdf)latex
```

When I tried compiling the document with the script provided it got stuck. Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: Use latexmk. It's in the disabled engines folder by default, but can be enabled easily. See [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271/all-in-one-engine-for-texshop) for how to do that. I *think* it will automatically figure out when you need to run makeglossaries or any other tool, but it can definitely be configured to do so.

Comment: Re latexmk and `glossaries`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create a file with

```
#!/bin/sh 
bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"  
pdflatex --shell-escape "$1"
makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".glg -o "$bfname".gls "$bfname".glo 
pdflatex --shell-escape "$1" 
pdflatex --shell-escape "$1"
```

You save this file with a name like `glossaries.engine` inside
      `/Users/yourusername/Library/TeXShop/Engines`

You need also to make excutable the script :

Go to the terminal : `cd ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` and then 
`chmod u+x glossaries.engine` use the name of your engine.

Then you can compile with the engine glossaries . Before to click on the compilation button, you need to chice the engine inside the list near the button "typeset", I suppose because in french, i have a "composition" button.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. However when I try to compile the document it gets stuck. I have added a screenshot to my question. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Go to the terminal : `cd ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` and then `chmod u+x glossaries.engine` use the name of your engine. I don't know if the encoding of the engine is important. I always use utf8.

Comment: You can also compile manually. Perhaps you have a problem with the file `.ist` if you use a specific file. You need to adapt the line `makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".glg -o "$bfname".gls   
"$bfname".glo `.

Comment: I recommend changing the explicit `makeindex` call to either `makeglossaries "$bfname"` (if Perl is installed) or `makeglossaries-lite "$bfname"`. That way it will also work with `\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}` or `\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification to [Alain Matthes' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43000) that determines whether to use `makeglossaries` (`makeindex`/`xindy`) or [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). Edit the `glossaries.engine` file to:

```bash
#!/bin/sh 

bfname=${1%\.*}

pdflatex "$1"

if grep -q "glsxtr@resource" "$bfname.aux"; then
  bib2gls --group "$bfname"

  # hybrid
  if grep -q "@istfilename" "$bfname.aux"; then
    pdflatex "$1"
    makeglossaries "$bfname"
  fi

elif grep -q "@istfilename" "$bfname.aux"; then
  makeglossaries "$bfname"
fi

pdflatex "$1"
```

This should work for all the following documents:

1. `\makenoidxglossaries` & `\printnoidxglossary`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}

   \makenoidxglossaries

   % define entry in default 'main' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

   % define entry in 'acronym' glossary:
   \newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}

   % define entry in 'symbols' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{fx}{name={\ensuremath{f(x)}},
    sort={fx},
    description={a function of $x$},
    type=symbols
   }

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printnoidxglossary % default: type=main
   \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
   \printnoidxglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```
2. `\makeglossaries` & `\printglossary` and `makeindex`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   % define entry in default 'main' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

   % define entry in 'acronym' glossary:
   \newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}

   % define entry in 'symbols' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{fx}{name={\ensuremath{f(x)}},
    sort={fx},
    description={a function of $x$},
    type=symbols
   }

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printglossary % default: type=main
   \printglossary[type=acronym]
   \printglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```
3. `\makeglossaries` & `\printglossary` and `xindy`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[xindy,acronym,symbols]{glossaries}

   \makeglossaries

   % define entry in default 'main' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

   % define entry in 'acronym' glossary:
   \newacronym{ex}{EX}{example}

   % define entry in 'symbols' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{fx}{name={\ensuremath{f(x)}},
    description={a function of $x$},
    type=symbols
   }

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printglossary % default: type=main
   \printglossary[type=acronym]
   \printglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```
4. `bib2gls`:

   ```
   \RequirePackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{terms.bib}
   @entry{sample,
     name = {sample},
     description = {an example}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \begin{filecontents*}{abbrvs.bib}
   @abbreviation{ex,
     short = {EX},
     long = {example}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \begin{filecontents*}{syms.bib}
   @symbol{fx,
     name = {\ensuremath{f(x)}},
     description = {a function of $x$}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[record,abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={terms,abbrvs}]

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={syms},type={symbols}]

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printunsrtglossary % default: type=main
   \printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
   \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```
5. `\printunsrtglossary` only:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

   % define entry in default 'main' glossary:
   \newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

   % define entry in 'abbreviations' glossary:
   \newabbreviation{ex}{EX}{example}

   % define entry in 'symbols' glossary:
   \glsxtrnewsymbol
    [description={a function of $x$}]
    {fx}{\ensuremath{f(x)}}

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printunsrtglossary % default: type=main
   \printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations]
   \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```
6. Hybrid `bib2gls`+`makeglossaries` (for example, if you have a custom `xindy` style that can't be replicated by `bib2gls`, but you want the convenience of storing entry definitions in `.bib` files):

   ```
   \RequirePackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{terms.bib}
   @entry{sample,
     name = {sample},
     description = {an example}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \begin{filecontents*}{abbrvs.bib}
   @abbreviation{ex,
     short = {EX},
     long = {example}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \begin{filecontents*}{syms.bib}
   @symbol{fx,
     name = {\ensuremath{f(x)}},
     description = {a function of $x$}
   }
   \end{filecontents*}

   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[record=alsoindex,xindy,abbreviations,symbols]{glossaries-extra}

   \makeglossaries

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={terms,abbrvs},sort=none,save-locations=false]

   \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={syms},type={symbols},sort=none,save-locations=false]

   \begin{document}
   A \gls{sample} document with an \gls{ex} function \gls{fx}.

   \printglossary % default: type=main
   \printglossary[type=abbreviations]
   \printglossary[type=symbols]
   \end{document}
   ```