# Problem with glossary

Tags: compiling, glossaries, itemize

I am copying the very first piece of code from [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) in order to create a glossary. While I get no problem in the compilation I do not get the "glossary part" that appears in the example. I literally copy paste.

Also, I want to create a document that only consists of a glossary of various terms. That is to put everything in alphabetical order (with the possibility to include references as well). How could I possibly do this? I tried some itemize options with alphabetical order but does not look that good.

Comment: Have you run the `makeglossaries` script as well or tried `\makenoidxglossaries` etc. ?

Comment: No, I just copied the code I found in ShareLatex. Do I do this in the preamble?

Comment: Please go the section 'Compiling the glossary' in the ShareLaTeX link you provided above..., it's at the bottom of that web page

Comment: Thanks. That does not help me though because it creates a file in the style of bibtex. I do not want to "call" my glossary, I want to create a document that itself is a glossary. Additionally I am not sure how to "call" the glossary in the main document. Am I supposed to do what they do but with my directory instead?

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about -- I have done many glossaries and answered many questions about it....

Comment: Are you trying to build the document in ShareLaTeX or on your local drive? If on ShareLaTeX, it should build it automatically. If on your local drive, what setup do you have (e.g. [TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152), [latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226), [WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119101))?

Comment: It works on Sharelatex but it is too slow. I am trying to make it work on TexShop.

Comment: @Gorbz Try  [this TeXShop solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43000).

Answer (score 1):

I will show you how to do it via command line on Windows 10. This can be done on Linux and Mac, or through your front-end (if you find out how to do it).

So,

1. Run pdflatex file.tex (or lualatex or xelatex):
   [image]
2. Run the file without extension with `makeglossaries`[image]
3. Do 1 again.
4. Enjoy the glossaries.[image]

Some explanation: `\makeglossaries` in the preamble tells TeX to collect all the related stuff and put it to the `.glo` file. When you execute `makeglossaries gl` or `makeglossaries gl.glo` from cmd, the file with extension `.gls` is created, which is used when compiling the main file (that's why the first run gives you a warning `gl.gls` not found).