# Different Font for different Languages (mixed in glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, languages, hebrew

I want to make a glossarie (using the glossaries-package) from Yiddish words (Hebrew script should be the Ezra SIL-font) from a main text. The description will be in German (Latin script = Linux Libertine). I have tried \begin{hebrew} … \end{hebrew} but it doesn't word (and makes the dokument bloated). Any suggestions? 
A glossarie entry looks like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{האנאָרים}{name={\RL{האנאָרים}},description={‘Freuden, Vergnügen’, \textit{hannáah} \parencite[90]{Tendlau1860}, \textit{hanō-e}}}
```

I hope it is not too messy:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ihead{\headmark}


\ohead{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}


\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} 

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000






\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{times,multicol,multirow, bigdelim}



%%%FONTS AND LANGUAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}




\usepackage{metalogo,hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}


\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{right}
%\setRlineflag{}



\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} 
\maxchunks{10000}


%START GLOSSAR%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\input{glossaries.tex}
\setglossarystyle{tree}
%END GLOSSAR%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}


\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}








\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=ngerman]{biblatex} \bibliography{LitGrobsdorfEdition}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}






\begin{document}



\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}\begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering

  \pstart     {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
   געלטע דאָס גִיט אָבער לאָסטיג
   \edgls{האנאָרים}
?}}  \pend

\pstart  {\RL{\speaker{בויער.}
  יאָ, דאָס גלעב אייך. הויא פערדיענסט דוא אַהך ניט פֵֿיעל. }}
 \pend

 \pstart   {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
    פֿערדיענט אייכס דאָך אין אַה פֿירטעל יאָהר, וואָהס מייכ‘ס הויא    און מאָר קאָסט.
\textit{)}\textit{זייפצט}.\textit{(}
}} \pend



 \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering



 \pstart  \speakerd{Person1.} {Gell}, Text…?  \pend

\pstart   \speakerd{Person 2.} Text…  \pend

\pstart    \speakerd{Person1.} Text…. \textit{(Seufzt.)} \pend


\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}


\end{pages}
\Pages



\printnoidxglossaries



\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be great if I could set in the preamble which font to use for which language (if Latex can recognize what is hebrew and what latin…)

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Try to use a standard font. If that's not possible and the question requires a specific font (is font-dependent), provide a link, if possible. Otherwise, be clear about what is needed as your question will only be answerable by those with the commercial font in question.

Comment: You have clearly tried something and found that it doesn't work. Do you mind sharing that with us in a [minimal (!) working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you're not using ASCII absolute don't use `\makenoidxglossaries`. Use `\makeglossaries` with `xindy`.

Comment: With `\makeglossaries` I don't get an output of the glossaries; with `\makenoidxglossaries` I do.

Comment: You need to run the `makeglossaries` script or invoke `xindy` manually to generate the glossary. Right now, we can't compile your example because we don't have `glossaries.tex`.  Is that just the sample glossary entry you gave?There is probably also stuff we don't need in your example.

Comment: `\makenoidxglossaries` doesn't use `xindy`. It performs a very simplistic character code comparison and won't recognise `\RL`. What interface are you using to build your document? For example, if you're using TeXworks see [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)

Comment: Ok, now I use 
`\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries`
But this doesn't solve my question: how can I use two different fonts with different languages in one script. Something like "everything in `\RL{}` should be typeset in EzraSIL and everything else in Libertine. My question has nothing to do with the glossarie-package in particular.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384098/37907

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It helps to start with a very simple document and build up from there. I don't have your Hebrew font, so I'm going to use Keter YG instead.

Initial minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
Deutsche
\end{document}
```

This produces an error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Linux Libertine" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

The font name should be `Linux Libertine O`. Once this is fixed, the example compiles fine, so now it can be extended to add Hebrew:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

This compiles fine, so now we can add `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

Now there's an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unable to properly define \@@leqno; primitive \leqno no longer primitive.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2568 \@saveprimitive\leqno\@@leqno
```

The problem here is that `glossaries` loads `amsmath` but `amsmath` expects `\leqno` to be a primitive. Unfortunately `polyglossia`'s `hebrew` setting redefines `\leqno` so it's no longer a primitive. The simplest workaround is to load `amsmath` first. (I'm not sure if this will cause a problem at a later date, but at least it gets rid of this error.)

So the modified example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

The previous error has gone but there's another error:

```
! Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package supertabular after 
bidi package. Please load package supertabular before bidi package, and 
then try to run xelatex on your document again.
```

The `glossaries` package automatically loads some predefined styles, including the `supertabular` styles in `glossary-super.sty`. The simplest solution here is to instruct `glossaries` to skip `glossary-super` with the `nosuper` option. There's a similar error for `longtable`, which is used by `glossary-long`. This can be omitted with `nolong`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy,nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

This restricts the available styles to the list and tree styles, but at least the example document now compiles. Since you've used `tree` in your question, I'll use that, but if you really want one of the tabular styles then load the relevant tabular package early. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy,nosuper]{glossaries}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

Now it's possible to add an example entry and a glossary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy,nosuper,nolong,style=tree]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{האנאָרים}{name={\RL{האנאָרים}},description={‘Freuden, Vergnügen’, \textit{hannáah}, \textit{hanō-e}}}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית

\gls{האנאָרים}
\end{hebrew}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This compiles without error but with a warning:

```
Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for `hebrew'.
(glossaries)                Language modules need to be installed separately.
(glossaries)                Please check on CTAN for a bundle called
(glossaries)                `glossaries-hebrew' or similar.
```

The `glossaries` package loads [`tracklang`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tracklang) to determine the document languages. It's picked up two languages: `german` and `hebrew`. There's support for German ([`glossaries-german`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-german)) but not for Hebrew, which is why there's a warning.

You can either ignore this warning (and supply your own translation) or copy `glossaries-german.ldf` to `glossaries-hebrew.ldf` and replace all instances of `german` with `hebrew` and all instances of `German` with `Hebrew` and replace the German text with the appropriate Hebrew translations.

If the file is called `test.tex` then the build process is:

```
xelatex test
makeglossaries test
xelatex test
```

If you don't have Perl installed (`makeglossaries` is a Perl script), you can use the lightweight Lua version `makeglossaries-lite` instead:

```
xelatex test
makeglossaries-lite test
xelatex test
```

Both `makeglossaries` and `makeglossaries-lite` pick up information from the `.aux` file, which tells them that the main document language is German, so `makeglossaries` does:

```
xindy  -L german -C din5007-utf8 -I xindy -M "test" -t "test.glg" -o "test.gls" "test.glo"
```

but `makeglossaries-lite` isn't quite as clever and misses out the `din5007` setting:

```
"xindy" -I xindy -L german -C utf8 -M "test.xdy" -t "test.glg" -o "test.gls" "test.glo"
```

So it's better to use `makeglossaries` if you can. At this point the document looks like:

[image: image of document]

I'm guessing that you actually want the glossary sorted according to Hebrew (since the `name` contains Hebrew characters). Since this isn't the main document language, you need to instruct `makeglossaries` (or `makeglossaries-lite`) to pass the `hebrew` setting to `xindy`. You also need to switch off the creation of the arabic number group. Like this:

```
\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong,style=tree]{glossaries}
```

Now decide is the glossary a Hebrew glossary with German descriptions or a German glossary of Hebrew terms?

In the first case the language needs to be switched when the glossary is displayed. Since there's no Hebrew support for `glossaries`, you need to set the title. As I can't speak Hebrew, I've just used Google translate to supply a title. Change it as appropriate. The German description needs to be set in German. This needs a custom style, which can be based on the `tree` style. Since this style automatically switches to Hebrew (using the `hebrew` environment) there's no need for `\RL` in the name. (`\gls` is also used in the `hebrew` environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{hebrewgerman}
{% base it on the tree style:
  \setglossarystyle{tree}%
  % switch to hebrew
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \begin{hebrew}
    }%
    {\end{hebrew}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreepredesc
    % put description and number list in German
    \textgerman{\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2}\par
  }%
}

\newglossaryentry{האנאָרים}{name={האנאָרים},description={‘Freuden, Vergnügen’, \textit{hannáah}, \textit{hanō-e}}}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית

\gls{האנאָרים}
\end{hebrew}

\printglossary[title={מילון מונחים},style=hebrewgerman]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of glossary]

This puts the description and number list in German. You can adapt the style according to your requirements.

If you want the second case, with German as the main language for the glossary, then a similar approach can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
{% base it on the tree style:
  \setglossarystyle{tree}%
  % switch to german
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \begin{german}
    }%
    {\end{german}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
      \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\newglossaryentry{האנאָרים}{name={האנאָרים},description={‘Freuden, Vergnügen’, \textit{hannáah}, \textit{hanō-e}}}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית

\gls{האנאָרים}
\end{hebrew}

\printglossary[style=germanhebrew]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

There are various ways of integrating `makeglossaries` into the build process.

### TeXShop

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43000), in order to use `makeglossaries` with TeXShop you can create a file containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"  
xelatex "$1"
makeglossaries "$bfname"
xelatex "$1" 
xelatex "$1"
```

Save it as `glossaries.engine` and follow the rest of the instructions in [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43000). A better approach is to use `arara`, described below.

### Arara

Install [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara) and add the following lines at the start of the document:

```
% xelatex
% makeglossaries
% xelatex
```

If the file is called `test.tex` then in the terminal just do

```
arara test
```

You can also add `arara` to TeXShop using a similar method to the above. Create a file called `arara.engine` that contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
arara "$1"
```

Make it executable (from the terminal)

```
chmod a+x arara.engine
```

Copy or move the file to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`

```
cp arara.engine ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines
```

Restart TeXShop and select `arara` from the dropdown list next to the `Typeset` button. (If you have a translated version, compare it against the image shown on the [TeXShop home page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop).)

If you then need to add a bibliography, just add

```
% arara: bibtex
```

or

```
% arara: biber
```

to the comments at the start of the file.

Complete example:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
{% base it on the tree style:
  \setglossarystyle{tree}%
  % switch to german
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \begin{german}
    }%
    {\end{german}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
      \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\newglossaryentry{האנאָרים}{name={האנאָרים},description={‘Freuden,
Vergnügen’, \textit{hannáah}, \cite{article-minimal}, \textit{hanō-e}}}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית

\gls{האנאָרים}
\end{hebrew}

\printglossary[style=germanhebrew]

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Another option is to use `latexmk`. See, for example, [How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries) (but make sure you don't use an answer that explicitly calls `makeindex` as `xindy` is required here).

Make sure you have the latest versions of all the required packages. You can add `\listfiles` to the start of your document to show the version numbers and compare them against the versions shown on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/).

Comment: any idea how I can get the line numbers in the glossaries using reledpar (\lineation{section})? using \edgls doesn't work here

Comment: The answer: 
`\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},counter=pageline,nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}
\glsSetCompositor{–}% Use - as separator
\pretocmd{\gls}{\doedindexlabel}{}{}% Call \doedindexlabel at the begining of \gls`

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך I don't recommended patching `\gls`. It's better to redefine `\glslinkpostsetkeys` instead. (`\renewcommand{\glslinkpostsetkeys}{\doedindexlabel}` or `\appto\glslinkpostsetkeys{\doedindexlabel}`) That way it will apply to all the indexing commands, such as `\glspl`, `\Gls`, `\glsdisp`, `\glslink`.

Comment: and how will I get the linenumbers with `\glspl, \Gls, \glsdisp, \glslink`?

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך I think it would be better to ask as a follow-up question with the MWE adapted to include `reledpar`.