# Glossaries and \libertineGlyph and \makebox

Tags: glossaries, libertine

I am having troubles using the Glossaries Package with some self-built hebrew characters using \libertineGlyph and \makebox. An entry looks like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}}{name={\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}},description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}}
```

Example:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

    \usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}

     \usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}

    \usepackage{scrpage2}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \clearscrheadfoot

    \ihead{\headmark}


    \ohead{\pagemark}
    \setheadsepline{0.4pt}
    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}


    \addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


    \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} 

    \clubpenalty=10000
    \widowpenalty=10000

    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim} %%deleted times


    %%%FONTS AND LANGUAGES

    \usepackage{fontspec}

    \usepackage{libertine}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}
    \setmainlanguage{german}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}


    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
    \usepackage{reledpar}

    \setgoalfraction{0.85}


    \lineation{section}
    \linenummargin{right}
    %\setRlineflag{}



    \linenumincrement*{5}
    \firstlinenum*{0} 
    \maxchunks{10000}


    %START GLOSSAR%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
    \input{../glossaries.tex}
    \setglossarystyle{tree}


    %% Glossary Entry
    \newglossaryentry{glosse1}{name={\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}},description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}}

    %END GLOSSAR%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\usepackage{metalogo,hyperref} 

    \Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
    \Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
    \Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}


    \renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}

    \newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

    \newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
    }

    \newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

    \newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
    {\textsc{#1}} \einzug
    }

    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}




    \begin{document}



    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}\begin{hebrew}
     \setRTL
     \beginnumbering

      \pstart     {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
       געלטע דאָס גִיט אָבער לאָסטיג
       \edgls{האנאָרים}
    ?}}  \pend

    \pstart  {\RL{\speaker{בויער.}
      יאָ, דאָס גלעב אייך. הויא פערדיענסט דוא אַהך ניט פֵֿיעל. }}
     \pend

     \pstart   {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
        פֿערדיענט אייכס דאָך אין אַה פֿירטעל יאָהר, וואָהס מייכ‘ס הויא     \edgls{glosse1}  און מאָר קאָסט.
    \textit{)}\textit{זייפצט}.\textit{(}
    }} \pend



     \endnumbering
    \end{hebrew}
    \end{Leftside}


    \begin{Rightside}

    \beginnumbering



     \pstart  \speakerd{Person1.} {Gell}, Text…?  \pend

    \pstart   \speakerd{Person 2.} Text…  \pend

    \pstart    \speakerd{Person1.} Text…. \textit{(Seufzt.)} \pend


    \endnumbering

    \end{Rightside}


    \end{pages}
    \Pages
    \printnoidxglossaries
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The first argument of `\newglossaryentry` must be a label. It can't contain any code in it. The label is used as a reference and is not typeset anywhere.

Comment: This can be – but it also has troubles when I have code inside the specification-part like "name=" or "description="  Is there any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Something like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}\makeglossaries \newglossaryentry{label}{name={\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}},description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}}}\begin{document}\gls{label}\printglossaries\end{document}` and add the packages that provide `\RL` and `\libertineGlyph`.

Comment: Off-topic. Don't load `times`. It is deprecated anyway and certainly irrelevant here. As @NicolaTalbot said, your `label` is bad. You need a simple text label here. Note that you aren't making it easy to help because anybody trying to help is going to get errors which are irrelevant. For example, your code requires a `glossaries.tex` in the directory above the working one, which most people won't have and won't be the same as yours anyhow. Also, if the problem can only be reproduced with that font, we'll need a link. Otherwise, try to use something people are likely to have already.

Comment: You need to load `polyglossia` before setting the languages. Surely you get an error from this? Also `hyperref` is being loaded too early. Can you not make your example smaller? Do you need the Biblatex and critical edition stuff? (This requests at least one more file only you have and nobody here can access.) I guess you know that `geometry` is not recommended with KOMA.

Comment: thank you for your notes. But I still have the problem with the glossarie. (I deleted the bibligraphy, this makes no trouble and isn't importand here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
\newglossaryentry{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}}{name={\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}},description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}}
```

has a serious problem. The first argument is a *label*. It's never typeset but is used as a reference (much like `\ref` and `\cite`), so there should never be any special characters in the label. With XeLaTeX, it's possible to use extended characters (as long as they're not active). So strip all markup from the first argument:

```
\newglossaryentry{עה}{name={ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה},
 description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}
```

`xindy` automatically strips commands and braces, so `\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}` will end up as `(-1,8)[r]uni02DC`, which is going to confuse the sorting. It's better to use the `sort` key to set an appropriate sort value that `xindy` can understand. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{עה}{name={ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה},
 sort={ע˜ה},
 description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}
```

or just

```
\newglossaryentry{עה}{name={ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה},
 sort={עה},
 description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}
```

Following on from [my answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384805/19862), here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Keter YG}

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
{% base it on the tree style:
  \setglossarystyle{tree}%
  % switch to german
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \begin{german}
    }%
    {\end{german}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
      \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}

\newglossaryentry{עה}{name={ע\makebox(-1,8)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה},
 sort={עה},
 description={‘Peace be with her’ oleho hascholaum}}

\begin{document}
Deutsche

\begin{hebrew}
עִברִית

\gls{עה}
\end{hebrew}

\printglossary[style=germanhebrew]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Comment: thank you so much for your work! It would be nice if this would work, but unfortunately it doesn't. Your minimal example as well as when I put it into my document; see: https://www.overleaf.com/10443287pndzdjcfndjy  (wich editor do you use? With TexShop (latest updates) this doesn't work :( )

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך That link isn't my minimal example. What happened when you tried to compile my example (without adding extra code to it)? In what way didn't it work? Any error messages? (I just use `vim` and run `xelatex` and `makeglossaries` from the terminal.) Have you tried building up my example from the start like I did? At what point did it stop working?

Comment: with TexShop it doesn't give an error-message with your code above; but it also doesn't print a glossarie. But I get this `Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for 'hebrew'.
(glossaries)   Language modules need to be installed separately.
(glossaries)                Please check on CTAN for a bundle called
(glossaries)                'glossaries-hebrew' or similar.
`
 With overleaf I get errors (https://www.overleaf.com/10443287pndzdjcfndjy) – but that is an overleaf problem I think

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך I've added TeXshop instructions. I've already mentioned that warning in my answer. There's currently no Hebrew support with `glossaries`. You'll have to provide your own translations.

Comment: thanks again! I've made such a file and but it in "Engine" order of TexShop. But still I don't get a Glossarie :(

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך Did you make the `glossaries.engine` file executable (using `chmod`)? Did you restart TeXShop and select `glossaries` from the engine list? Is there a file with the extension `.glg` in your document directory (with all the other temporary files like the `.log` and `.aux` file)?

Comment: what did you mean with "select glossaries from the engine list" ? (sorry)

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך I'm sorry, I don't have TeXshop so I was just guessing from what I'd read. If you look at [this image of TeXshop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/picture.png) next to the "Typeset" button there's a dropdown menu (showing "LaTeX" in the picture). If you click on that, it should list all the available engines, so the new `glossaries.engine` should show up there. (I expect you probably have `XeLaTeX` currently selected.)

Comment: thank you again. Now I see. But even if I am running the document with glossaries I don't get a glossarie – I will try some other things…

Comment: there is still the error `Package glossaries Warning: No language module detected for `hebrew'.`

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך No, it's not an error. It's a *warning*. You can ignore it and provide your own translation through the `title` option (as I did in one of my examples). If you still can't get the glossary to appear, try [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get the output you have. Could you tell me how you compile it (via terminal and Perl)? Are you using XeLaTeX? It would be sad if all your work would be for nothing just because I am too dump compiling it :(

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך  Using a terminal on Linux (should be much the same as on a Mac) and assuming the file is called `test.tex`: `xelatex test; makeglossaries test; xelatex test`. Principle dependencies: `glossaries` v4.30 2017-06-11, `makeglossaries` v2.21, `glossaries-german.ldf` v1.0, `tracklang` v1.3.4 2017/03/25, `polyglossia` v1.42.4  2015/03/25, Perl v5.18.4 (add `\listfiles` to the document to get a summary at the end of the transcript)

Comment: I think it might be better if I move most of this answer to [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383784/different-font-for-different-languages-mixed-in-glossaries).

Comment: thank you! It works like this perfectly :) Maybe you move it to the answer too! (I am so relieved, that it works!)

Comment: just one more thing: If I want to include a bibliography how do I compile biblatex (biber) with the terminal?

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך  I'm sorry I realise that I missed a comma between the `sort` and `description`. That might have been causing a problem. I've moved most of the answer to the other question and I've included a bibliography at the end of it. You can adapt it from `bibtex` to `biblatex`.