# Declare Font for specific Language

Tags: fonts, languages, hebrew

I am using two very different languages mixed in a document: Hebrew and German. For the Hebrew text I want to use the EzraSIL font, for German Linux Libertine. I don't want to use something like `\begin{hebrew}…\end{hebrew}` because it messes things up. The Hebrew parts are already "tagged" with `\RL{}` so perhabs one can define, that everything between `\RL{}` will use the EzraSIL-font?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383784/37907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\setmainfont{Fontin Sans} %just for contrast

\newcommand{\hb}[1]{\texthebrew{#1}}


\begin{document}
Dies ist ein Text auf deutsch.

\texthebrew{זהו טקסט עברי.}


\hb{עוד טקסט בעברית}


\end{document}
```

Note that Linux Libertine already has Hebrew characters, so using a single font for both languages would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks!!! (The Linux Libertine Hebrew font is not that nice)

Comment: Leah, if it worked for you, you might consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך You can change the lines to `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}` and `\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}`. שָׁנָה טוֹבָה.