# Using Terminal to run LaTeX commands

Tags: compiling, indexing

Since I always used TeXShop to compile my `tex`-files I did not have to run LaTeX commands via terminal (many macros like `BibTeX`, `MakeIndex` etc. are included in TeXShop). Now that I want to include an index and change its style I need for my understanding to run the following command in terminal to generate a `.ist` file:

```
makeindx -g -s a:\mkidx.ist MyIndex.idx
```

I just do not know how to run (LaTeX-)commands via Terminal. Can anyone help?

Comment: Chances are you don't need to run latex from the terminal to do this.  You might want to check out the `latexmk` Engine for TeXShop.  See [All-in-one-engine for TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41271/2693).

Comment: The package [`imakeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) provides easy access to makeindex' options without the need to use the command line. You have to run your document with `shell-escape` enabled, though.

Comment: You can say `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and `\makeindex[options=-g -s mkidx.ist]`; you won't even need to run `makeindex` from the Terminal, as the package takes care of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Terminal, and use `cd` to get to the folder containing `MyIndex.idx`. If the folder is your home directory, then just `cd ~` will do the trick, otherwise `cd ~/Documents` for your Documents folder, etc. Then just enter the command, which is probably

```
makeindex -g -s mkidx.ist MyIndex.idx
```

rather than what you have above (i.e. `makeindex` in place of `makeindx` and no `a:\` which looks like MS-DOS to me).

This assumes that Terminal knows where to find `makeindex`, which may not always be the case, depending on how your system is set up. If it fails, use Spotlight to find a file called `makeindex`, and add its location before `makeindex`. On the machine I am using, `makeindex` is located in `/opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/`, so the above command becomes

```
 /opt/local/libexec/texlive/binaries/makeindex -g -s mkidx.ist MyIndex.idx
```

Comment: I get the following `makeindex -g -s mkidx.ist MyIndex.idx
-bash: makeindex: command not found`

Comment: @John --- I have edited my answer.

Comment: If @John is using a standard MacTeX installation, he won't have a `/opt` directory, since that is installed by MacPorts.  The standard path for TeX binaries in MacTeX is `/usr/texbin`.  It's possible  that John's path is set incorrectly in the terminal.  Similarly, Spotlight is usually set not to index system files, so it usually won't find TeX related files by default.

Comment: @AlanMunn ---- On the machine I am using (which is quite old) there is no setting to determine whether Spotlight should index system files. Could you add a comment explaining how to turn this feature on when it is optional?