# Not generating the .aux for the bibliography to run

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, auxiliary-files

I'm trying to generate my bibliography and, for what I read, I need to run my `main.tex`, then `bib.aux` and then, again `main.tex` twice, right?

I have created my `.bib` file and the name on the `\bibliography{bib}` is the same as my file.
The thing is, although I have saved the `bib.bib`, when I run `main.tex` the `bib.aux` is not generated. I saved the bib file as a TeX bib file. It's correct, right?

I'm working on a Mac OS, does this make it different?

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The `.aux` generated for `bibtex` is `main.aux` not `bib.aux`

You should run

```
latex main
bibtex main
latex main
```

(and possibly other times. It happens that `bibtex` has to be run twice or more, when using crossreferences).

Some packages use other `.aux` (see e.g. `multibib` package), but this is not your case.

Comment: Thank you. But where do I type those commands? I am using TeXShop, and every time I need to check on my pdf I just click on Typeset on the menu bar, I never had to type any command lines. I tried to do it in the console for the main.tex but nothing happens...

Comment: I already solved the problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear and without an MWE I can only guess. I think there are some missunderstandings causing your problems.

First of all have a look on my MWE, store it with the understandable filename `mwe-bibtex.tex` (`main.tex` can be nothing or everything ...):

```
%File mb-bibtex.tex, then \jobname = mb-bibtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}            % loading package filecontents 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography
% writing file \jobname.bib
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}  
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994}
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
The funny book of Adams~\cite{adams}, the \LaTeX{} companion~\cite{companion}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

Run it first with typing `pdflatex mwe-bibtex.tex` in your terminal comand line.
You will find a new file `mwe-bibtex.bib` (comming from the used package `filecontents`in my MWE) containing the data of a example bibliography. Now run `bibtex mwe-bibtex`. This builds, using the file `mwe-bibtex.aux`, the file `mwe-bibtex.bbl` LaTeX needs to include a correct bibliography in your document. Now run LaTeX twice with `pdflatex mwe-biblatex.tex`. Afterwards you should have a `mwe-biblatex.pdf` file containing the complete document.

Please test first my MWE on your system. Is it running change your code accordingly.

**Update:**

With TeXShop you can also run `pdflatex` and `bibtex`. Perhaps question [all in one engine for texshop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271/all-in-one-engine-for-texshop) can help you. Otherwise have a look into the TeXShop manual.

Comment: Thank you, I see the point. But I may also create the .bib file by myself, right? Ok the problem I'm having now is that I don't know where to type the pdflatex and bibtex commands. I am using TeXShop and I never had to type any commands to generate my pdfs. Eventhough I tried to use the terminal on mac and I couldn't run the bib file. It showed:bibtex: Not writing to /Users/juliocosta/Desktop/cenalatex/mwe-bibtex.blg (openout_any = p).
I couldn't open file name `/Users/juliocosta/Desktop/cenalatex/mwe-bibtex.blg'

Comment: I already solved the problem. Thanks for your time. I managed to run it on terminal and got your file right, and then applied to mine.

Comment: @Luis: fine. Please upvote and accept that answer that helps you most. Package `filecontents` is a good thing to have two complete files in one compiling MWE :-)

Comment: @Cadoiz The warning is okay. For the error please ask a new question and add into your question which TeX distribution and which version you are using (copy the first line of the resulting log file to your question).

Comment: Thank you! Deleted the comment and created this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559236/110394 The `filecontents` env should now also be build into recent LaTeX and `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}` can be used to overwrite the file each time. This makes changes to it in the `filecontents` env possible that will be added to the `.bib` file. Normally, if the file already exists, latex will leave it alone. Link to the quoted user: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif

Comment: I also applied a small fix to your MWE by moving a comment according to @daleif, hope that's alright. For user and reference to the question please refer to the comment above. moewe also added a comment finding that comment to be misplaced. ( https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe )