# Bibliographies producing [? ] or `I couldn't open file name 'titlesec.aux'` respectively

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex, texstudio

#### Actual Problem

The issue that I'm actually trying to resolve is that TeXstudio gives me `Citation 'mykey' on page 9 undefined` (more about the error in the appendix below).
I'm however not bound to TeXstudio but believe that the problem lies somewhere else/below.

---

#### Research so far

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined) seems to be a related question. Following the suggestions in [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153652/110394), I ran the bibliography module (`bibtex.exe`), which leads to this error: `I couldn't open file name 'titlesec.aux'`.

Looking for a way to tackle this (I found almost nothing), I tried [this MWE which is provided here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74276/110394):

```
%File mb-bibtex.tex, then \jobname = mb-bibtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}            % loading package filecontents 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}  % writing file \jobname.bib
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994}
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
The funny book of Adams~\cite{adams}, the \LaTeX{} companion~\cite{companion}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

I compiled it from console and also using TeXworks. After pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to forward from this error output:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.7 \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
                                         % writing file \jobname.bib
?
```

a .pdf is generated, but it still lacks correct quoting. The previous output in TeXstudio was something like `foo[mykey] bar`, now I get `[? ]`:[image: Wrong Quotation like [? ]]

Coming from the comments section [ibidem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74276/110394), this question here arises.

---

#### Installed versions:

- TeXstudio 2.12.2 (Qt-Version 5.6.2)
- TeXworks 0.6.5 (MiKTeX 20.7)
- first line of `texput.log`:

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.8.18)  19 AUG 2020 11:02`

- JabRef 5.0 (should not be relevant)
- `pdflatex --version`:

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.0.1 (MiKTeX 20.7)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with jpeg version 9.3
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

---

#### Appendix:

*Full error that is tooltipped while hovering over a simple* `\cite{mykey}`

```
Zitat fehlt: 
mykey
```

*(engl.: ~"Quotation missing").*

Comment: If your latex installation is up to date the `filecontents` env is now build in. Your problem goes away for me if I remote that comment after `\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib`.

Comment: TIP: If you use the new latex then one can use `\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}` then the bib file is overwritten each time, thus you vcan make changes to it in the `filecontents` env and it will be added to the `.bib` file. Normally, if the file already exists, latex will leave it alone

Comment: You seem to have missed the last two lines when you copied the MWE: `\bibliography{\jobname}` and `\end{document}` are missing. If I remove the problematic comment `% writing file \jobname.bib` in the `filecontents` environment, things work for me. Can you please make these changes, run the example in a new, empty folder and edit your question accordingly?

Comment: The message `I couldn't open file name 'titlesec.aux'` sounds a bit odd. It either suggests that you are calling BibTeX on `titlesec.sty` (presumably because your editor has focus on `titlesec.sty` and not your main `.tex` document) or that your `.tex` file is called `titlesec.tex` (which should be avoided: I have seen some weird side-effects when people used the name of a common package for their `.tex` file. Call it `cadoizdoc.tex` and try again.).

Comment: @moewe Sorry, you're absolutely right. I missed the scrollbar and didn't include the last two lines in the question. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Please also remove the inocrrectly placed comment `% writing file \jobname.bib`. Then run the MWE in a new, empty folder and update your question with what you see then (there shouldn't be any `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` error message).