# how to use latexdiff with TexShop?

Tags: texshop, latexdiff, mac

I am trying to use latexdiff to compare two tex documents on my macbook pro. I use TexShop to compile my latex documents. I know the latexdiff package is already installed with under the Tex folder, but I do not know how to use it.

I have these questions:

1. how to use latexdiff? do I click latexdiff then the Terminal shows up? then do I write the command there `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`?
2. I have tried this, but I could not write anything in the Terminal. Is this related to security issue or not?
3. if I want to compare two tex files, where or under what path should I put these two tex files?
4. do I run latexdiff script in TexShop with macros or applyscript?

I hope someone can give me some suggestion. I would be very grateful

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: For your Q4: [Create an engine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271/all-in-one-engine-for-texshop) would help. Then you can compare the current file `$1` and some old file `$1-old`.

Answer (score 14):

latexdiff is installed in MacTex under /usr/texbin/latexdiff. No need to install it separately. To use latexdiff,

1. open Terminal;
2. change the directory to the one where you put old.tex and new.tex; for example, I put my two tex files on Desktop, so I just write `cd /Users/xxxx/Desktop` in Terminal("xxxx"is my user name);
3. then write: `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`.

Job done.

Answer (score 0):

The latex-diff website returned "<filenames> require package `ulem` to compile", when I tried to use it with my two files.  I had commented out this package in my LaTeX files, so I uncommented them and still got this message.  As I understand the message, the website itself requires `ulem` in order to compile the files that are being compared.  Strange if it didn't have it.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, there is a very simple solution, just use http://3142.nl/latex-diff/ this service, then generate a new `.tex' file which will produce the desired pdf.