# Is it possible to use \IEEEeqnarray in beamer?

Tags: beamer, ieee-style

I have a report written in `IEEEtran` class. Now I need to make slides in `beamer`. There are lot of equations formatted according to `\IEEEeqnarray` with different alignments, so it will be cumbersome to transform them all to either `\align` or `\eqnarray` environments which are possible environments in beamer.

I am curious if there is any way to use `\IEEEeqnarray` environment in `beamer` class? I did try `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`, but its not working in following example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {   
    \usetheme{Warsaw} 
    \useoutertheme{infolines} } 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images 
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} \bibliography{references} 
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} 
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %for slide transition %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %  TITLE PAGE %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title[\date{\today} ]{Heading} % The short title 
\author{kaka} % Your name \institute[my univ] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space { My University \\ % Your institution for the title page \medskip \textit{kaka@tata.com} % Your email address } \date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}  
        \frametitle{Overlapping Composite Binary Hypotheses}   
        Due to the uncertainty in the noise variance, composite binary hypotheses ....... 
        \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl} 
            SNR&=&\dfrac{E[|\vec{a}^ {\ \dagger} \vec{b}s|^2]}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} \\ 
            &=& \frac{E[|s|^2]\cdot |\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{b}|^2}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} 
        \end{IEEEeqnarray*}             
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible. You are already using `IEEEtrantools`.

Comment: It is commented out. When I use IEEEtrantools, it comes up with an error.

Comment: The code in the following answer works for me. How about for you? Does it work?

Comment: if you are on MiKTeX, you might need to download http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools/IEEEtrantools.sty into your working directory. If this is the fix, your error has been `File IEEEtrantools.sty not found. \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` and would have been interesting for us.

Comment: This is the error I am getting ........File `IEEEtrantools.sty' not found. \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already using `IEEEtrantools`, hence it is possible to use `IEEEeqnarray`. The following works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines} }
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}   %% makes IEEE tools available in other classes.
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}  \frametitle{Overlapping Composite Binary Hypotheses}   Due to the uncertainty in the noise variance, composite binary hypotheses ....... 
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl} 
SNR&=&\dfrac{E[|\vec{a}^ {\ \dagger} \vec{b}s|^2]}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} \\ 
&=& \frac{E[|s|^2]\cdot |\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{b}|^2}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} 
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you are also loading `mathtools`, the job done by `IEEEeqnarray` can be easily done by `align*`

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines} }
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}  \frametitle{Overlapping Composite Binary Hypotheses}   Due to the uncertainty in the noise variance, composite binary hypotheses .......
\begin{align*}
SNR&=\dfrac{E[|\vec{a}^ {\ \dagger} \vec{b}s|^2]}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} \\
&= \frac{E[|s|^2]\cdot |\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{b}|^2}{E[|\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{w}|^2]} \end{align*}

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As suggested by LaRiFaRi, you may want to add the option `retainorigcmds` to `IEEEtrantools`, if you want to use only `IEEEeqnarray*`.

Comment: same error....File `IEEEtrantools.sty' not found. \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

Comment: @kaka Then you have to install it. But it comes with both miktex and texlive.

Comment: @kaka have you tried what I recommended in comment above? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91672)

Comment: I am looking and working on it. Many thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Many Thanks for guiding the blind. It is nicely working now.