# Problem with IEEEeqnarray

Tags: errors, ieeetran

I installed Miktex 2.9 on a new machine, but it seems I cannot use `IEEEeqnarray`. I followed the instructions on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91672/3954) to [Using IEEEtrantools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28198/3954) to install `IEEEtranstools.sty` but it is not working.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
x = y
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Missing = inserted for \ifnum
Missing number, treated as zero
```

UPDATE:

Based on suggestions in the comments, I removed the environment and run the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\listfiles
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\errorcontextlines=20
\begin{document}
%\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
%x = y
%\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

and here is the content of the .log file after *File List*

```
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
IEEEtrantools.sty    2012/12/27 V1.3 by Michael Shell
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 566 strings out of 493921
 9634 string characters out of 3144871
 56485 words of memory out of 3000000
 3943 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,1n,23p,206b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get those error messages with the *exact* code you posted? I ask because your code works with no problems in my system (TeX Live2015).

Comment: Yes, I got the errors with exactly the same code.

Comment: Can you add `\errorcontextlines=20` at the beginning of the file and then report the *exact* error message?

Comment: @egreg I added it in the preample and I still get the *exact* error message.

Comment: @Noor Look in the `.log` file

Comment: @egreg the '.log' file is long. Perhaps this is the part you are looking for 
"l.5 \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't."
Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Noor Yes, but the information you're giving is insufficient. Try removing the environment, but adding `\listfiles` at the top of the document. Compile and report what you find in the log file after `*File List*` (add to your question).

Comment: @egreg I updated the question based on your suggestions.

Comment: My TeX distribution has `IEEEtrantools.sty    2015/08/26 V1.5`; also your `report.cls` is outdated. Update your MiKTeX and retry.

Comment: @egreg Problem solved. Thanks a lot. Please add your last comment as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `IEEEtrantools` is outdated: the most recent one is

```
IEEEtrantools.sty 2015/08/26 V1.5
```

Upgrade your TeX distribution.