# How to align the equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I hope to align equations as shown here:
[image]

I used this code:

```
\begin{align*}
    \displaystyle {eq1} &\Longleftrightarrow& \displaystyle {eq2}
    \\\\
    \displaystyle {eq3} &\Longleftrightarrow& \displaystyle {eq4}
\end{align*}
```

Each eq#s' length is different. If I use this code, then my result is like the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `alignat` environment.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
  aaa&=bbb &&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad & ccc&=ddd \\
  a  &=b   &&\quad\Longleftrightarrow      & c  &=d
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Mmm… It seems to work because both sides of equalities have the same length.

Comment: @Bernard: I assumed the OP wanted the equations on both sides of `\Longleftrightarrow` to be aligned at the equal sign, and my solution delivers this. However, if OP wanted the equations to be center-aligned, regardless of the connectives, then your solution (or Werner's) will be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, we took a different point of view. The O.P.'s sketch seemd to mean both sides had some axis of symmetry.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using an `align*`, I assume you're not interested in numbering the equations. As such, using an `array` allows you the freedom of specifying your alignments as you wish:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove horizontal column separation
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Stretch vertically
  \begin{array}{ *{3}{>{\displaystyle}c} }
    \mbox{a very long LHS} & {}\Longleftrightarrow{} & \mbox{a very long RHS} \\
       \mbox{short LHS}    & {}\Longleftrightarrow{} &    \mbox{short RHS}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with the `eqparbox` package. I define an `\eqmathbox`command, which types its contents in displaystyle math mode. It  uses a `tag`  which ensures all boxes with the same tag will all have the width of the largest contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[Eq#1]{\ensuremath{ \displaystyle#2}}}

 \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
    \eqmathbox[1]{\text{a very long equation}} & \Longleftrightarrow \eqmathbox[2]{\text{a still looooonger equation}} \\
       \eqmathbox[1]{\text{a short equation}} &{} \Longleftrightarrow \eqmathbox[2]{\text{a shorter eq}}
  \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `IEEEeqnarray` environment is bulky, but powerful. It lets you have several aligned columns, and it also gives you the proper spacing around your `=` and `\Leftrightarrow` signs.

```
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rClCrCl}
   aaa & = & bb & \Leftrightarrow & cccc & = & dd
\\ e & = & f & \Leftrightarrow & g & = & hhhhh
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Nice-looking equations.]

IEEEtrantools is well-maintained, but notoriously hard to install. [This StackExchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/using-ieeetrantools) provides a good guide to the process of installing it properly, but a completely workable option is just to download IEEEtrantools.sty from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) and leave it in the same folder as your code.