# How to add a custom .sty file to MiKTeX Portable?

Tags: packages, miktex

How do I add a custom .sty file to MiKTeX Portable?

Adding it to `.\tex\latex\misc` and then refreshing the database doesn't work -- Xetex still avoids searching for the file altogether, outside of the current `.tex` file directory.

Comment: Put the `.sty` file in the _same_ directory as your `.tex` document. XeTeX (or LaTeX) searches in the current directory, but does not go into subdirectories.

Comment: @LianTzeLim: I don't want to do that for every single document I use the file in. It needs to become part of MiKTeX Portable itself.

Comment: You are not giving enough precise informations. It is unclear in which tree (if any) `.\tex\latex\misc` is and how exactly you refreshed the database.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I'm at the root MiKTeX Portable directory, so the folder is `<miktex-root>\tex\latex\misc`. I refreshed the database by clicking on `Refresh FNDB` in MiKTeX Options.

Comment: Did you try another tree mentioned in the miktex settings, e.g. UserConfig? Or can you create your own local tree? (I never used the portable version, so I don't know how it manages its tree).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I indeed did, but it was a subtree of MiKTeX Portable's own directory, so it didn't help. I was hoping I could keep it in there somehow, but I guess I can't...

Answer (score 7):

Apparently MikTeX Portable doesn't like custom additions to its own `TEXMF` tree. You'll have to create your own tree, say in `E:\own-texmf` (let's assume `E:` is the thumb drive containing your MikTeX Portable installation.

Put your custom `.sty` in, say, `E:\own-texmf\tex\latex\misc`.

Then in the **MikTeX Options** dialog, switch to the **Roots** pane, and add `E:\own-texmf` to the list of registered root directories.

Now go back to the **General** pane, and **Refresh FNDB**. MikTeX Portable should now be able to see your custom `.sty` file.

Comment: Oh huh... so there's no "correct" way to embed it inside MiKTeX Portable? +1 thanks for the info.

Comment: @Mehrdad Guess not for the present. I'm not sure if the MikTeX maintainer has a reason for making it this way; you could try contacting him and ask if it's possible to rectify this in future versions. Also, if you think this answer is satisfactory enough, appreciate it if you could "accept" it (by clicking the green tick symbol), so as to have as few "unanswered" questions as possible on the site. :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: It wouldn’t work with not portable MiKTeX, too. If you have MiKTeX portable on a removable drive, you should of course put your local TeXMF onto the same drive. Inside of MiKTeX the relative path will be saved. See also [Setting TEXMFHOME variable when using Miktex portable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46145/setting-texmfhome-variable-when-using-miktex-portable).

Comment: “I'm not sure if the MikTeX maintainer has a reason for making it this way; you could try contacting him and ask if it's possible to rectify this in future versions.” Setting a local TeXMF tree inside of MiKTex worked in earlier versions (I had managed it this way), but was changed with version 2.8 or 2.9 for security reasons, don’t know exactly anymore. So, I guess it will *not* reversed by Christian Schenk (the MiKTeX maintainer).

Comment: I was going to wait a little and see if maybe someone else will have another idea, before I accept this answer. :) But thanks for the reminder, I went back and accepted the ones I'd forgotten to.

Comment: @Speravir: I haven't accepted an answer because it's more of a 'workaround' than a solution, but I've upvoted it because it's still a good workaround. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "some other answers to other questions"...

Comment: @Mehrdad: No! It’s **not** a workaround, it’s the usual way of MiKTeX handling.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old thread but just for documentation... I could install a custom package into a portable miktex installation. It appears that miktex portable doesn't like you adding packages into texmfs\install directory. You should create your own install folder and drag'n'drop packages from tds.zip files to there. Add this folder to path list in MikTex Options > Root, so Update FNDB normally. It have to work now.