# TexMaker/Miktex package not found although installed

Tags: packages

I'm using the portable version of MikTex 2.9 and TexMaker. 
Yesterday, I installed the package "acronym.sty" using the package manager.

Back at work today, I get the following error message:

> The required file
>     tex\latex\acronym\acronym.sty
>   is missing. It is part of the following package: acronym.sty

When I go to tex\latex\acronym\acronym.sty, I can clearly see that there is a file acronym.sty. I also tried to Update FNDB, but it didn't help. I also can't try to simply reinstall the package, because I don't get ftp: access at work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you choose your package repository manually, you should be able to pick one that works with http? So my guess would be trying to uninstall and reinstall the package that way.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading comment: I can't even connect to the Internet via mikTex: get host by name failed in tcp_connect()

Comment: Doesn't work via http, see my previous comment.

Comment: In case you're using Windows: Did you use the 'Administrator' version of the maintenance dialogue? Using this one solved a font installation problem with similar symptoms I recently had.

Comment: In the worst case you can copy the sty to your document folder. Then it will be found. But it would be better to find out what wrong with the normal location. I never used the portable version but imho there are 2 possible sources for the problem: the FNDB has not been updated correctly or the root with the package is not registered at all. Try if the command line too `initexmf --report` shows the root.

Comment: How did you the installation, and how did you execute TeX/(PDF)LaTeX (from which command prompt)? Compare also [Using MikTex Portable, TexMaker, and Asymptote from a USB drive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51110/9237).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the package manager did not work properly. The following procedure solved the problem:

- add the package in the preamble using "\usepackage{requiredPackage}
- compile the file and wait for popupwindow that suggests to install missing package (appears in texMaker / miktex)
- accept installation, package will be properly installed