# texmaker 3.5 miktex portable 2.9 and epstopdf

Tags: miktex, texmaker, epstopdf, portability

I am using TeXMaker 3.5 (same problems in TeXMaker 3.4.1) and MikTeX 2.9. My source is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure} 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{test.eps} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

But I always get:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `test-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

MikTeX is working! The picture also exists and using the command prompt:

```
G:\LaTeX\sandbox>G:/miktex/miktex/bin/epstopdf --outfile=G:\LaTeX\sandbox\test-eps-converted-to.pdf G:\LaTeX\sandbox\test.eps
```

produce the pdf from the eps-file. This is my configuration:

```
 Tools\Latex="\"../miktex/miktex/bin/latex.exe\" -enable-write18 
 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"  Tools\Dvi=../miktex/miktex/bin/yap.exe -1 -s @.tex %.dvi 
 Tools\Dvips=\"../miktex/miktex/bin/dvips.exe\" -o %.ps %.dvi 
 Tools\Ps=../gsview/GSviewPortable.exe %.ps 
 Tools\Ps2pdf=\"../miktex/miktex/bin/ps2pdf.exe\" %.ps 
 Tools\Makeindex=\"../miktex/miktex/bin/makeindex.exe\" %.idx 
 Tools\Bibtex=\"../miktex/miktex/bin/bibtex.exe\" %.aux 
 Tools\Pdflatex="\"../miktex/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe\" -enable-write18
 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"  Tools\Pdf=../SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe %.pdf -reuse-instance
 -forward-search %.tex @  Tools\Dvipdf=\"../miktex/miktex/bin/dvipdfm.exe\" %.dvi 
 Tools\Metapost="\"../miktex/miktex/bin/mpost.exe\" --interaction
 nonstopmode " 
 Tools\Ghostscript=\"../miktex/ghostscriptx/bin/gswin64c.exe\" 
 Tools\Asymptote=../Asymptote/asy.exe %.asy 
 Tools\Latexmk="\"G:/miktex/miktex/bin/latexmk.exe\" -e
 \"$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode/\" -pdf %.tex" 
 Tools\Sweave=../R/bin/R.exe CMD Sweave %.Rnw
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem? I have created my [portable version here](http://files.wieschoo.com/usblatex.rar).

Thanks in advance. I tried all possible permutations of `--enable-write18`, `--shell-escape`, `-enable-write18`,....

Comment: I suppose, it’s a question of the search path. What does the log file say? Cf. also my answer to “Using MikTex Portable, TexMaker, and Asymptote from a USB drive” http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51110/9237.

Comment: Here is the logfile:
http://pastebin.de/29075

Comment: Edit your question and paste in the lines from “(epstopdf) Output file: <test-eps-converted-to.pdf>” until “runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=test-eps-converted-to.pdf test.eps)...executed.” Compare the log file, that you created with the command line execution. I’m even more convinced right now, that the search path is the problem. Try out the last part of my above linked answer, replace “ASYPATH” with “SANDBOX” or “LOCALTEX” or whatever you want, and “<path-to-asymptote-executables>” with “LaTeX\sandbox”.

Comment: Run on the command line (in a folder which contains only the test document and the eps-graphic) `pdflatex --shell-escape test` and show the log-file. In case that pdflatex is not found change in the command line at first the PATH variable: `set PATH= path\to\miktex\bin;%PATH%`.

Comment: Wieschoo: In my humble opinion you should have it mentioned here on TeX.SE, that you asked the same on another place: golatex.de/texmaker-3-5-epstopdf-t9439.html (I’m not a regular reader of Golatex.de, but found it by accident).

Comment: I would post here, I there were solutions at other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After (re-)installation of MiKTeX portable and some try&error I found out, that the real answer is … *RTFM:*

Excerpt from the `epstopdf` manual:

> **Note:** Usually the conversion program needs the exact location of the image ﬁle. Usually the current directory works. Also if the image ﬁle is found using `\graphicspath`, the location is known. However, if the image is somewhere in a directory of environment variable `TEXINPUTS`, then the package does not know the exact location and the conversion program will not ﬁnd the image ﬁle unless it implements a search using `TEXINPUTS` (program `kpsewhich` may be of help in this task).

So, you have the choice between following 3 possibilities:

1. To the call of `pdflatex` add the commandline switch `--include-directory="G:\LaTeX\sandbox"` (Attention! No closing backslash here, or, if the path is without white space, leave out the double quote marks), but included inside of TeXMaker it’s not portable.
2. Add the command `\graphicspath` to your TeX file. In a test I had to use slashes instead of the usually in Windows used backslashes. That’s also not portable, but you can easily change it, before you do a new compiling.

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage{graphicx} 
   \graphicspath={{G:/LaTeX/sandbox/}}
   \usepackage{epstopdf} 
   \begin{document} 
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{test.eps} 
   \end{document}
   ```
3. <strike>What I would favour:

   Similar as I already pointed out in [Using MikTex Portable, TexMaker, and Asymptote from a USB drive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50911/using-miktex-portable-texmaker-and-asymptote-from-a-usb-drive/51110#51110) – edit the start file `miktex-portable.cmd` (make a safety copy first) and add the system variable `TEXINPUTS`. Note: The way it’s shown here, it works only, if the `TEXINPUTS` directory is on the same drive as the portable MiKTeX installation, and as far as I see, it’s the only portable way.</strike>

   ```
   @echo off

   set MOBIDRIVE=%~d0
   set TEXINPUTS=%MOBIDRIVE%\LaTeX\sandbox        
   set PATH=%TEXINPUTS%;%PATH%

   miktex\bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe
   ```

   Then you can (and should!) use the command line prompt, that you get with right click on the traybar icon. The command line compilation worked fine here in a test. Start TeXMaker from this command prompt or add a line

   ```
   start /i /d%MOBIDRIVE%\<path-to-texmaker> texmaker.exe
   ```

   **before** the above `miktex\bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe` or create an own startbatch file with the variable `TEXINPUTS`.

**Remark:** After I’ve done a test with TeXMaker portable (BTW: that’s actually not fully true!), that I had to download first, I must say, that obviously with TeXMaker this approach of point 3 didn’t work! Only with the `\graphicspath` version or, if the EPS file was in the same directory like the TEX file, I’ve got a result. *(Remark 2: I used some example files of Ghostscript and the example folder as graphics path, everything was on the same drive.)*

I leave the not functioning point here, because wieschoo’s answer refers to it.

Comment: surrender

Hi,

first of all thank you. I tried all your suggestions. But they don't work at my computer. 

After reinstalling I have the following folder structure:
G
- latex (for documents)
- texsuite
   - miktex (portable 2.9)
   - texmakerwin32usb (texmaker)
   - gnuplot

I found out that the command
pdflatex -output-directory=G:\latex\ -undump=pdflatex G:\latex\works.tex

works well using the prompt and produce the pdf. This command doesn't work in TexMaker.

I give up. I can't understand why there isn't a portable package that contains some applications and miktex itself.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I found usbtex from 
http://www.exomatik.net/U-Latex/USBTeXEnglish 
and use their idea and your (Speravir, thank you) suggestion.

First:
Install miktex portable as usual.

Second:
create folderstructur of the usb like
- documents
- texsuite
-   - MiKTeX_2.9   (miktex 2.9)
-   - gs9.02         (ghostscript) 
-   - texmakerwin32usb (texmaker 3.5)
-   - tikzedt   (tikzedt 0.2)
-   - gnuplot   (gnuplot)
-   - texmaker.bat
-   - tikzedt.bat

`texmaker.bat`

```
set path=%~dp0MiKTeX_2.9\miktex\bin;%~dp0gs9.02\lib;%~dp0gs9.02\bin;%~dp0gnuplot\bin;%PATH%
cd %~dp0texmakerwin32usb\
start texmaker
```

`tikzedt.bat` (for Tikzedt)

```
set path=%~dp0MiKTeX_2.9\miktex\bin;%~dp0gs9.02\lib;%~dp0gs9.02\bin;%PATH%
cd %~dp0tikzedt\
start tikzedt.exe -p
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment: If both `texmaker.bat` and `tikzedt.bat` are inside of `texsuite`, as you show in the folder structure, then your settings were wrong. I’ve changed it now.