# Texmaker / TeXstudio does not compile XeLaTeX with MiKTeX portable

Tags: xetex, compiling, miktex, texmaker, texstudio

I am trying to migrate from TeXworks to Texmaker (just for the fact that it is better for handling multi-files projects). I am using portable versions of both MiKTeX and Texmaker, so, in Texmaker I went to Options > Configure Texmaker > Commands and point every command available to the current path of MiKTeX. And it works just fine with PDFLaTeX, but at the moment I try to compile some XeLaTeX document it just do not generate any PDF output.

For a brief moment, in the log frame says that it can not recognize `xdvipdfmx` as a program or a command. So I figure that it is trying to find it in the default installed MiKTeX directory (because `xdvipdfmx.exe` indeed exist in the same folder than `xelatex.exe` and TeXworks never has a problem finding it). There is an option to set the path to `dvipdfm` (which —I am guessing— works with PDFLaTeX), but not for `xdvipdfmx`.

So, a concise question would be, Is there a way to change (or add) the default directory for Texmaker to look for? Or is the problem another?

**[Addendum]** [edited] So, I decided to put a `xdvipdfmx.bat` file into the Windows folder (which only contains one line: `E:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\xdvipdfmx.exe`), and now it appears that compiles as it should, BUT it does not produce any PDF file, even tho the log file ends saying “Output written on satre-merleau-ponty-levinas.pdf (175 pages)” or, if I add an `\includeonly` sentence, “Output written on satre-merleau-ponty-levinas.pdf (9 pages)”. Every auxiliar file is also created, just not the PDF. Any thoughts?

A minimal example (not PDF output generated) is

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,book]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Under this conditions: MiKTeX portable 2.9, Texmaker portable 3.5.2 (or TeXstudio portable 2.5)

It indeed generates a PDF output if I compile it from TeXworks OR if I comment out the `\usepackage{fontspec}` line and compile it with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: You must activate the creation of the according format files first. See this answer of mine http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71460.

Comment: Also search here on TeX.SE for the (not so much) questions and their answers, put in the search: `[miktex] +portable +texmaker`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still doesn’t work. Frankly, I don’t think there’s anything wrong with MiKTeX or its configuration (besides, it compiles as expected with TeXworks). The error said that it can’t execute `xdvipdfmx.exe` because it can’t find it; I just want to know how to point Texmaker to it… or whether that’s possible or not.

Comment: I do not have more clues, then. If `pdflatex` wouldn’t have worked, too, I would have thought, it was a system path issue, and suggested to read the answers in [texmaker 3.5 miktex portable 2.9 and epstopdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68768/texmaker-3-5-miktex-portable-2-9-and-epstopdf), but so unfortunately I cannot help.

Comment: Regarding your addendum: Please post the content of the `bat` file. Also try out the direct command line call of the `xdvipdfmx.exe`. And I think, it is time for you to provide a [minimal (not) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will (not) compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Oops, noticed just now: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/discussion/33789/thread/74621cdc/

Answer (score 1):

This is not the optimal response, but it is an answer. You have to edit the *path* enviromental variable to add, at the end of it, the path to the `bin` MiKTeX folder (thanks to [Speravir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9237) for pointing it out). In this case, just add `;E:\LaTeX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin` (the semicolon is the separator). A guide to do that is in http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm.

The compiling worked in TeXworks because it sets one folder to look for all the programs, while Texmaker and TeXstudio set the path individually. So, I’m not sure if the fault is in MiKTeX or in the editors just mentioned.

So, what if I wanna use Texmaker from an usb in a computer with no admin rights? Well, just be sure to carry TeXwork (which comes with MiKTeX anyway), then work and save in Texmaker, and then compile from TeXworks.

Comment: The bad thing is, in this way your MiKTeX distribution is not portable anymore! Try to modify your `miktex-portable.cmd` similar as shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51110/9237 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68915/9237 (in the striked out part).