# Using Asymptote with MiKTeX

Tags: installing, miktex, asymptote

[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) is shipped out with TeX Live, but not with MiKTeX, not even with a full installation.

Do you nonetheless know a way for manual installation? MiKTeX needs to know the path of the `sty` files, and the Asymptote binary file needs to know the path of the `asy` scripts. Thought of adding the Asymptote folder to the list of registered root directories in MiKTeX, but MiKTeX complains, that this would be “Not a TDS-compliant root directory”.

<sub>There is already a similar question: [Using MikTex Portable, TexMaker, and Asymptote from a USB drive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50911/using-miktex-portable-texmaker-and-asymptote-from-a-usb-drive).</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, there is a description in the Art of Problem Solving Wiki, [Asymptote: Advanced Configuration – Using Asymptote in LaTeX](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Asymptote%3a_Advanced_Configuration#Using_Asymptote_in_LaTeX) (also linked in the question regarding portable use), we can partly adapt, but *in one point I want to strongly discourage you following this*: Instead you should *install the `sty` files in a local texmf tree*, about the reasons you can read in [Purpose of local texmf trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees).

This will be successful (WinEdt users read [Harish Kumar’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106637/9237) first, please):

- Download Asymptote from http://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/ and install, where you want. I will use here `C:\Program Files\Asymptote`.

  <sup>The binary in TeX Live is newly built from sources, has some dependencies of other TeX Live binaries and find its `asy` scripts with the builtin `kpsewhich` mechanism. Hence in difference to [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex/71168#71168) the installation from TeX Live files is not recommended.</sup>
- If not already done [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).
- Create a subfolder `<localtexmf>\tex\latex\asymptote` and copy the three `sty` files from the Asymptote main directory in it.
- Create an empty file in `<localtexmf>\bin\` with the name `asymptote.bat` (or with extension `.cmd`).

  Copy the following, paste it into the batch file and adjust the path according to your setting:

  ```
  @echo off
  SETLOCAL

  SET AsyPATH=C:\Program Files\Asymptote
  SET PATH=%AsyPATH%;%PATH%

  asy.exe %*
  ```

  This will also ensure, that the Asymptote binary finds the preshipped script files. A remark: When you save the file in Notepad or Wordpad, make sure, that there is no automatic appending of TXT extension – save the file name with double quotes: `"asymptote.bat"`.
- Refresh the file name database (FNDB). BTW I assume here, that you followed the instructions and added `<localtexmf>\bin` to the system path. Actually the batch script could be put elsewhere, as long as it was in the system path.
- Asymptote needs also Ghostscript. You have 3 specific opportunities to make it known (adjust path, of course):

  - Directly adding the command line option
    `-gs="<path\to\ghostscript>\bin\gswinc32.exe"`.
  - Adding the environment variable

    `ASYMPTOTE_GS=<path\to\ghostscript>\bin\gswinc32.exe`.
    (Note, that this did actually not work in my computer, but I didn’t restart.)
  - The preferred variant for frequent users: Create a file `config.asy` in Asymptote’s main directory with following content

    ```
    import settings;
    gs="<path\to\ghostscript>\bin\gswinc32.exe";
    ```

Now you can execute Asymptote in your actual work folder. Let’s make a test: Copy the file `latexusage.tex` from Asymptote’s `examples` subfolder into a test folder, I will use `c:\test` here. Open the Command Prompt and execute

`cd /d c:\test`,

the `/d` switch ensures, that you can also change in one step to another drive.

Then compile with your TeX editor or execute

`latex latexusage`.

This will create 3 `asy` script files. These 3 files must now be executed with

`asymptote latexusage-1.asy`

(you could also omit the file extension) and so on for the others.

Then again compile with your TeX editor or execute

`latex latexusage`.

The result must look as shown below (I cropped it a bit). In Adobe Reader the interactive example works fine as well.

[image: example output]

Comment: Harish, please read carefully: I created a batch file `asymptote.bat` _and **this** is called with `asymptote`_. In this batch you can find the call of `asy.exe`.

Comment: OOps! Sorry. It means the batch file did not work for me. Hence I kept getting the error. I went blind Sorry `:-)`

Comment: Then either the batch is not in the system path or there is something wrong in the batch file itself.

Answer (score 9):

## For winedt users:

Install [asymptote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/) as explained by speravir.

Copy `asycolors.sty`, `asymptote.sty` and `ocg.sty` from asymptote installation folder (`C:\Program Files\Asymptote`) to your `localtexmf` folder (for me it is - `C:\Local\texmf\tex\latex\asymptote`).

Run a file name database refresh (FNDB) from the MikTeX options.

Create a `config.asy` for `gswinc32` as explained by speravir. Note that the `asymtote.bat` file won't be necessary.

Download and install the winedt macro [asymptote](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Asymptote.html).  You will get a toolbar button and menu item under TeX.

[image]

[image]

You are good to go.

Comment: +1 we can see `asy` posts from now on :) , I think `arara` can automate `asy` and `pdflatex` sequences.

Comment: Upvoted. And I added a link to your answer in mine.

Comment: @texenthusiast: Idea is to learn asymptote first :-). Arara can certainly automate this with ease.