# Getting TeXnicCenter to see Asymptote

Tags: texniccenter, asymptote

I am re-installing my LaTeX system onto a new computer, and am having trouble forcing Asymptote to output PDF files. As always, I've been following the instructions on the Art of Problem Solving website. When I try to compile my asymptote, I get the message "cannot find module '%tc-*.asy'". Can somebody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add the link to this page on “Art on problem solving” you refer to (I know [Asymptote: Advanced Configuration – Using Asymptote in LaTeX](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Asymptote%3a_Advanced_Configuration#Using_Asymptote_in_LaTeX)). Also you should give us your actual configuration. And do you use TeX Live or added you Asymptote manually? In second case: Did you follow an instruction (add the link)? Just as reference: [Using Asymptote with MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83035).

Comment: I think it's http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/.