# Asymptote usage in the LaTeX Workshop extension in VS Code. The '.latexmkrc' file

Tags: asymptote, vscode, latex-workshop

I'm trying to create a `pdf` document using the [LaTeX Workshop v8.29.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop#:%7E:text=LaTeX%20Workshop%20is%20an%20extension,Jerome%20Lelong%20%40jlelong) extension in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs). And I'm using [asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io) by writing `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}` in my `.tex` file preamble and wrapping asymptote code in the `\begin{asy} \end{asy}` environment. Suddenly, instead of displaying the picture in my document the program just skips some space on the page, and I get the `file 'file_name-1.tex' not found` error. At the same time, `file_name-1.asy` appears in the folder containing my `.tex` file.

It seems that VS Code looks for a `.tex` file instead of a `.asy` file. I've seen an [issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/354) on this topic and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583833/asymptote-figures-not-rendering-in-vs-code) question, where I found that adjusting a `.latexmkrc` file could help. But what is this file? Where and how should it be created/named/changed?

My OS is Windows 11.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue, I am in the same position right now