# How to get capital letters in the titles of a biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I am using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) together with biber and the [`biblatex-fiwi` package.](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-fiwi)

Each word in the title data entry of the items in my bibliography should have an initial capital letter. Is there any easy way to force `biblatex` to display all the entries in my bibliography this way? Which file(s) do I have to edit and which line of code do I have to add?

The `biblatex`-command in my `.tex` document looks like this:

```
\usepackage[style=fiwi2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

`fiwi 2` is my current bib-style. I guess I have to change/add something in the `.bbx` or `.cbx` files of the `fiwi` package?

Comment: Try `\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\MakeCapital #1 }`

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the suggestion. I changed my Tex-File and the `fiwi2.bbx`-file. According to [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/where-can-i-put-biblatex-style-modifications), both should be possible, but unfortunately, nothing worked - all book titles are displayed as before.

Comment: And the star version `\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{\MakeCapital #1 }`

Comment: @Marco Done :-) This didn't help either. I guess it doesn't matter whether I edit both files simultaneously or only one at a time? I also tried `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeCapital{#1}}`, buiding on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22980/sentence-case-for-titles-in-biblatex); I suppose the difference is that the latter command applies to _all_ titles, not just book titles?

Comment: @muderseb I don't think the fiwi styles use the `titlecase` format. The package author does frequent this site. Perhaps you can wait for him to respond or contact him directly.

Comment: @Audrey A very useful information indeed, thanks! I'll contact him and post his suggested solution here.

Comment: @Audrey Although I was not able to find Philipp Lehman, the author of `biblatex`, I had more luck with Simon Spiegel. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to send private messages to particular users in this forum, so let's hope he finds my question first :-)

Comment: @muderseb -- His email is listed on the `README` of his package and on the first page of the manual.  You could contact him that way..?  (Note also that Philipp Lehman is not the person to contact for styles based on his `biblatex` package.)

Comment: Hello. I would really like to see how this matter was answered.

Comment: @Costi Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111134/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-biblatex