# Capitalize the first letter of each word in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I'm trying to get every word in the title of each article in my reference list in capital letters (So Something Like This For Every Title). However, somehow `\MakeSentenceCase` remains active no matter what I do. This is how I am trying to get this done:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\MakeCapital{#1}}
```

[The manual](http://ftp.sun.ac.za/ftp/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) also mentions `\MakeUppercase`, which I have also tried, and nothing changes either. When I use `\textbf` (just for testing purposes), then the titles *do* turn into boldface titles. So `DeclareFieldFormat` does work, just not `MakeCapital`.

Comment: related: [Command to uppercase the first letter of each word in a sentence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7992/command-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-sentence?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\MakeCapital` works only for the fist letter of the complete argument. As far as I understand `biblatex` there is no special macro for converting every first letter of a word into uppercase.

Here is an example how it may be possible. I used a book entry for this example (you can change it to whatever you need:

```
 \RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@BOOK{Freeman:2003,
  title = {The measurement of environmental and resource values: Theory and
    methods},
  publisher = {Resources for the Future},
  year = {2003},
  author = {A. Myrick III Freeman},
  address = {Washington},
  owner = {Asus},
  timestamp = {2012.04.06}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\FirstLetterUppercase#1{\expandafter\FirstLetterUppercase@i#1 \@nil}
\def\FirstLetterUppercase@i#1#2 #3\@nil{%
  \MakeUppercase{#1}#2
  \ifx\relax#3\relax\def\next@i{}\else\def\next@i{\expandafter\FirstLetterUppercase@i#3\@nil}\fi%
  \next@i}
\makeatother
\renewbibmacro*{title}{\printtext{\printfield{title}}\newunit}
\DeclareFieldFormat*[book]{title}{\protect\FirstLetterUppercase{#1}}
\begin{document}

\FirstLetterUppercase{now i will see what happens.}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]