# How to install biblatex style?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, aiaa

I am having a problem getting my LaTeX to recognize biblatex styles using bibtex8 as a back-end. I've used this notation before but when I update LaTeX it clears my styles folder and I'm never able to find the configuration again. I would like a straightforward explanation of what my problem is.

The following notation gives `Package biblatex Error: Style 'aiaa' not found.`

Putting the style file in the same directory as the .tex file does nothing. I need to know how to install it more basically than that.

Using OS X TexShop 3.98

Cheers.

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-pretty}% insert '[draft]' option to show overfull boxes

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
```

`\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,autocite=superscript,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true,style=aiaa]{biblatex}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
    \let\cite=\autocite`

Comment: What is the exact name of the aiaa-style file you are trying to use?

Comment: Looking for `aiaa` in TeXLive reveals only a `.bst` file, which is not usable with `biblatex`.  Have you downloaded a `biblatex` style from somewhere? If so it should have a `.bbx` and possibly also `.cbx` extension. If not, then you can't use `biblatex`.

Comment: Did you get the files from https://github.com/nasa/nasa-latex-docs/tree/master/support/biblatex/aiaa? Or did you indeed only download the `.bst` files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer aiaa.cbx /aiaa.bbx /aiaa.bst . I got all of them from the NASA github, in the same directory.

Comment: @AlanMunn I've added all of them from the NASA github, to the same directory; the same error persists.

Comment: Where did you put the files, though? You can't just put them anywhere and expect TeX to find them. ([Instructions for MikTeX on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864), [Instructions for TeX live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864)). If it's just for this paper just put `aiaa.bbx`, `aiaa.cbx` in the same directory as your main `.tex` file. (You don't need `aiaa.bst` for `biblatex`.)

Comment: @moewe indeed I put them in the same directory as the main .tex file. It does not seem to find them. I guess I need to find the LaTeX install configuration in order to put them in the correct BibTex style folders so that it can recognize them.

Comment: If you have the `aiaa.bbx` and `aiaa.cbx` in the same directory as your main `.tex` file and you start LaTeX in that directory then TeX must find the files. Double check that everything is as you think it is.

Comment: In particular the `.bbx`/`.cbx` files can't be in a subfolder, they must be on the exact same level as the `.tex` file. Double check that your editor does not do weird things such as using a "build directory". Does LaTeX produce a `.log` file in the same directory?

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to get things running?

Comment: Any news here? Did you find a way to use the style?

Comment: Any news here? If there is no feedback here in due time, I will vote to close as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40243/35864

Answer (score 3):

If the style you want to use is included in MikTeX or TeX live, the easiest solution is to install the package via your TeX distribution.

---

If, on the other hand, the style is not available in your TeX distribution, you have to go about this manually.

In case you only want to use the bibliography style for your current document, it is enough to move the `.bbx`, `.cbx` (and possibly `.dbx` and `.lbx`) files into the same directory as your main `.tex` file. TeX will then find all the files when it is run in that directory.

For styles that you intend to use more often and extensively and in several documents that may live in different folders, you need to install the style in your local `texmf` tree.
Check back with the source of your files, maybe it has an install script or a installation guide.

On a **TeX live** system you should move your `.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.dbx` and `.lbx` files to

```
TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/<your biblatex style>/
```

On many systems `TEXMFHOME` is `$HOME/texmf`. You can find its value with `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`.

Alternatively, you could install the files to

```
TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex/<your biblatex style>/
```

again, you can find out where that is exactly with `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`.

Depending on your system settings you may have to run `texhash` to make the new files known to TeX.

See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-install-where, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-privinst and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-what-TDS

In a **MikTeX** system you may have to define a user-controlled `texmf` tree first (see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/35864)), but then the method is similar: Move the files to

```
<my local MikTeX texmf tree>/tex/latex/<your biblatex style>/
```

and refresh the file name database.

See also [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864) and [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/35864) and the resources linked there.

Comment: To summarize: install new Bibtex Style in texlive system:

1. ```kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
     -->  /usr/local/share/texmf```

2. On a TeX live system you should move your .bst, .bbx, .cbx, .dbx and .lbx files to
    TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/<your biblatex style>/

3. Example: move plaindin.bst into new TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/plaindin/ directory. 

4. Then call the tool "hexhash"

Comment: @karsten In principle yes. Though `biblatex` styles should not come with a `.bst` file. On my system `.bst` files live in `TEXMF/bibtex/bst`, so logically I think `.bst` files should go into `TEXMFHOME/bibtex/bst/<style name>/` (but I haven't checked if that is necessary for `kpsewhich`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes if I question ```TEXMF``` I get a whole list of paths (comma-separated), where on my Ubuntu 20 system the directory of `TEXMFHOME` is also contained. Using subdirectory `bibtex/bst/<style name>` is cleaner.
I found other .bst files in  `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst`

Comment: SORRY TYPO: use `texhash` NOT `hexhash`