# Problem with installing TeX Live under Windows 8

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I am new to LaTeX and wanted to install the required "programs". But when I came to installing TeX Live, there seemed to be a problem:

```
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at (directory)
```

I have no idea what to do, I simply just downloaded the zipped file from the internet, unzipped it at a random location and tried to run it from cmd.

My PC is recently formatted with Windows 8 and I haven't installed anything with LaTeX before on it. Hope someone can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Win 8! good for you:-)

Comment: Have you tried MikTeX, it is not texlive but usually works good on windows systems?

Comment: No, I was just recommended to use this :)

Comment: Interesting links: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex and http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/09/15/MiKTeX-on-Windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 8):

For me this was also a problem with the PATH-variable.

Go to environmental variables, search for PATH and add at the end: `;C:\Windows\system32`. The semicolon is important as it separates the entries.

You can test it by typing `cmd` into the console. If it works (and you had the same problem like me), `tlmgr` may now update properly.

Restart the console after changing environmental variables.

---

Thanks a lot. That was my problem, too. I added ";C:\Windows\system32" at the end of the PATH environmental variable - and the installation worked out fine. You amde my day! :-)

Comment: cool! thank you! This also solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am running TeXLive on Windows 8 x64 and there are no compatibility issues that I can see. Just to double check your procedure:

- [Download install-tl.zip for Windows from CTAN.](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip)
- Extract the ZIP to a destination of your choice, preferably with 7-zip. The extracted folder has 49.9 MB, 2,973 files and 407 folders on my system.
- Run `install-tl.bat` by simply double clicking on it.

I did not have to do anything else, as such the installation for me is identical to previous issues. If this does not work try:

- Rightclick on `install-tl.bat`
- Select `Run as Administrator`

Hope that helps, but I don't see why there should be any issues.

Comment: I’m installing texlive on Windows 7. Running install-t1.bat didn’t work for me (some error on cmd prompt). However, I had more success with running the install-t1-advanced.bat. The installer has a GUI interface showing detail installation process. Thanks for your helpful post.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, seems that the problem is related to the environmental variables in Windows 8. I changed the variable "PATHEXT" (it holds the sequence that Windows looks for executables in) from ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;...." to ".EXE;.BAT;.COM"...., this fixed the problem for me. Environmental variables are found under

```
Controlpanel>System and security>System>Change settings>Advanced>Environmental variables
```

(translated from danish).

Happy TeXing!