# How does one install TeX Live in Windows 8?

Tags: installing, texlive, windows

I have Windows 8. I just downloaded the TeX Live distribution from CTAN. When I double click on `install-tl.bat`, I receive the following error message:

```
PATH=C:\Users\JAKEFI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOFD2B.tmp\tlpkg\tlperl\bin;C:\Progra
m Files\7-Zip\;C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window
s;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.AC
E\Core-Static
"C:\Users\JAKEFI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOFD2B.tmp\install-tl"
'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Two questions. (1) Is there any useful information contained in the above error message that would help me to install? (2) If not, are there alternate installation methods?

FWIW I have also tried using `install-tl-advanced.bat`. There is no error message, but the computer doesn't do anything either.

Comment: There are some external programs that use on [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) but surely not the core of TeX. For some reason, the installation routine you chose uses Perl. I’m not familiar with Windows 8 and/or TeXLive but on MikTeX on Win7 does not interfere with Perl. Are there any other installation routines available (preferably `.exe`s)? Maybe [Problem with installing TeX Live under Windows 8](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83363) does help (Administrator rights and/or environment variables)?

Comment: If tied to TexLive could you just [install Perl](http://www.perl.org/get.html) and try again? I have TexLive working and now that I think about it, I can't think of another reason why I would have installed Perl.

Comment: What exactly did you download? On Windows, you need the `.zip` file, which you should extract then run the installer. From your error, I wonder if you tried to run the installer without extracting the files.