# Equivalent to TeXLive's --restricted-shell-escape for MiKTeX?

Tags: miktex, windows, minted, shell-escape, security

I often work on Windows, so need to use MiKTeX. I recently found the `minted` package, which needs to call the external command `pygmentize`. I currently call `xelatex` with the `-shell-escape` option to support this, but I'd rather not give malicious latex files complete access to my system. TeXLive has the `--restricted-shell-escape` option, which is what I want, but it doesn't seem to be available on MiKTeX. I did find a passing reference to `--shell-restricted`, but I don't know if that's what I want, and if it is what I want I don't know how to use it.

Is `--shell-restricted` a way to tell XeLaTeX to run `pygmentize` but not `del /F /S /Q C:\*.*`? If so, how do I use it? If not, is there such a way and how do I use it? If you can, could you also link me to the official documentation on the subject?

Comment: Well miktex installs a documentation on your system. And it mentions `--restrict-write18`. `--shell-restricted` could work too - miktex often has alias names for some commands. Restricted write18 is enabled by default, but I don't know if your command is in the list of secure commands.

Comment: The `minted` package explicitly checks if `\pdfshellescape` equals 1, so you'd have to change the package, even if you succeed into putting `pygmentize` ampng the allowed programs for restricted shell escape.

Comment: I could always edit my local copy of the package to change the 1 into a 2 (or better yet, find a way to check if `pygmentize` is specifically available). That still leaves the problem of making it available. Now that I realize that `\write18` is the method of accessing external commands, I can check its documentation and see if I find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiKTeX includes the option `--restrict-write18` to allow a restricted set of commands to be run: this is enabled by default with an up-to-date MiKTeX. However, to allow this to work with `minted` there are two additional issues. First, you need to add `pygmentize` to the list of allowed commands: a separate question on this (probably for the 'general case') would be best. Secondly, `minted` checks for fully-enabled `\write18` before it will even run: circumventing this would require a modified version of the package or a request to the package author to change the code.

As an aside, TeX Live runs fine on Windows, but of course you'd still have to deal with the two caveats.