# Auto Package download for TeXLive

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, texlive, linux

I use MiKTeX on Windows and quite satisfied with it. Recently I started switching all my tasks toward open-source alternatives, and in the course I would love to use Linux. In Linux TeXLive is available as alternative to MiKTeX. The thing I really like about MiKTeX, is its ability to install packages automatically. Can I do the same in TeXLive too? Is there a way I can enable such or install some plugins for it?

I am using Fedora 18, if that's needed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I am sorry, but did I break any rules of posting?

Comment: You are new, so @Jubobs was being friendly :-)

Comment: @rafee: No, not at all. `:)` We just greet new users to TeX.SX that way and usually provide a link to our quick primer.

Comment: Oh!! That link scared me!!

Comment: If you install the complete TeX Live collection (~2400 packages) you'll never ever need to add new packages. Everything will work just fine and all you'll need to do will be a matter of `tlmgr update -all` from time to time or `tlmgr update <package>` if you need something specific. As a Linux user I strongly suggest you not to install your distribution packages but go directly to the source and install TeX Live via one of [these](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) methods. This is closer to the Unix way of doing things and you will not regret it in the long run.

Comment: @dcmst I agree with you, but devoting 2 GB+ for latex, doesn't seem very convincing for me. I would rather install packages one by one.

Comment: Related [What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20036/15717)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While in MiKTeX an installation process is automatically triggered if you have, say, `\usepackage{beamer}` in a document preamble without the corresponding package installed, there is no such feature on TeX Live.

*The last statement is not true actually, as pointed out by wasteofspace in the comments there is the [texliveonfly](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texliveonfly) package that implements the on demand installation in TeX Live 2010 and later. I never tested it and don't know if it has drawbacks.*

However, if you install the full (or almost full) TeX Live collection of packages (~2400) you will not need to add new packages, a periodic `tlmgr update -all` will take care of everything, including the installation of packages added to the TeX Live collection after you first full installation. This feature is explained in the `tlmgr` manual.

> Analogously, if a package has been added to a collection on the server
>   that is also installed locally, it will be added to the local
>   installation. This is called `auto-install` and is announced as such
>   when using the option `--list`. This auto-installation can be suppressed
>   using the option `--no-auto-install`

The manual has lots of info on useful commands and it is a [recommended reading](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) for every user.

The downside is of course that you need the full set of packages installed in your machine, which may be a problem if you don't have enough free space. If you really can't spare 2GB from your HD, it is also possible to install TeX Live in a, say, 4GB [USB key](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable) and live happily ever after :)

Everything I just wrote requires that you install TeX Live with one the methods described [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html). If you decide to use the TeX packages from your distro you are forced to follow their update policy, which is different for different distros

Comment: *never*???!  so the op will never be interested in an update, or in a new package?  intriguing.  i would suggest the `texliveonfly` package.  (i can’t recommend it, since i’ve never used it, but it looks appropriate.)

Comment: The OP will never have to _care_ about packages because (i) he already has all available packages at the time of installation and (ii) packages added to TeX Live list after the first install will automatically be added via `tlmgr update -all`. I think that in the end you will install the vast majority of packages anyway, so it is simpler to just install everything and forget about it. However the package you mentioned looks interesting, didn't know about it, too bad I can't test since I already have the full installation ;)

Comment: can I use texliveonfly with TeXstudio?
I tried replacing pdflatex command with "texliveonfly.py %tex", but that didn't do the job

Comment: It works for me with the following command: `texliveonfly --compiler=pdflatex <filename>.tex` (issued from a terminal, I don't know about TeXstudio). If you aren't using lualatex you need to specify the compiler with an option, since the default is set to `lualatex`. Also the documentation of the package is outdated, since the option `--engine` is no longer recognized. To be sure that everything is set to work, check if the a script called `texliveonfly` is inside your `/bin` directory.

Comment: thanks, I found the way. Its "/bin/texliveonfly" %.tex in place of pdflatex window. And the package works like a charm. Thanks to @wasteofspace for that

Comment: btw `\usepackage{beamer}` does not make much sense :D

Comment: I have the texliveonfly script in my /bin folder but for example if I do: \usepackage{euscript} in TexMaker it doesn't work.

Comment: @rafee I would be very wary of this, personally. Either it is installing into the main or local tree, which it ought not have permission to do, or it is installing packages into your personal tree. That is asking for trouble and will certainly cause headaches - especially, though not only, in the case of font packages. If people use this, they should make absolutely certain they understand what exactly it does and that they know when they need to undo things and which errors and problems to look out for.

Answer (score 19):

### texliveonfly

As mentioned in [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/auto-package-download-for-texlive#comment243163_110533), there is a TeX Live package called [`texliveonfly`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly) which you can use with `texliveonfly filename.tex`, and it will automatically downloaded the right TeX Live packages.

This also works for packages for which the LaTeX package name and the TeX Live package name don't match (for example the LaTeX `rubikrotation` package is contained in the `rubik` TeX Live package), and it also takes package dependencies into account.

#### Usage

**Installing** It is a Python script so it requires Python to be installed. You can then install it like usually with `tlmgr install texliveonfly`. If you have to use `sudo tlmgr` here, you will have to use `sudo texliveonfly` later.

**Running** If you go in your terminal to the directory of your `filename.tex` file, you can run it with `texliveonfly filename.tex`.

**Other compilers** At the moment it uses `pdflatex` by default, but you can configure it to run with other compiler engines by using the `--compiler` (or `-c`) flag, so like `texliveonfly --compiler=lualatex filename.tex`.

**Compiler flags** You can pass flags for the compiler you use to `texliveonfly` using the `--arguments` (or `-a`) flag, so for example if you previously used `latexmk -shell-escape -pdf filename.tex` then you now use `texliveonfly --compiler=latexmk --arguments='-shell-escape -pdf' filename.tex`.

**Known problems**

1. There are some cases of missing packages which fail with a non-standard error message, for example babel when it's missing languages, in which case `texliveonfly` doesn't download them.
   At the moment the following packages are known to have to be installed manually: (please edit if you find more)

- Babel languages, for example for european languages install the `collection-langeuropean` package
- Biblatex styles, e.g. for the nature style you need the `biblatex-nature` package
- fontenc encodings, e.g. to get `t2aenc.def` you need the `cyrillic` package, and to get the `ly1enc.def` you need the `ly1` package.
- Packages involved when using the minted package, which are `minted fvextra upquote lineno xstring framed caption` (thanks to [pablgonz for testing](https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf/pull/24))
- When running external programs like `texcount` in your LaTeX file, texliveonfly does not detect that you need the `texcount` package.

2. When giving options to texliveonfly, for example for a different compiler, it sometimes hangs for no apparent reason when installing packages. You can most probably work around it by first running texliveonfly without options, so `texliveonfly main.tex` (so it will download the packages) and then running whatever you wanted to, for example `latexmk main.tex`.

#### Background

Essentially texliveonfly is a build tool like latexmk (which is a Perl script), it wraps the TeX engine. Note however that you can chain them with `texliveonfly --compiler=latexmk filename.tex`.

It is a python script which works by trying to run your LaTeX file, and if it fails because a package is missing it will try to install that package.

Besides on [ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly](https://ctan.org/pkg/texliveonfly) you can view the source at [ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texliveonfly](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texliveonfly) or on [latex.org/forum](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15194)

PS I tested this on Arch Linux 4.19.4 and on Travis CI (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: To create the package list you can use the following trick, first `pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode "\RequirePackage{snapshot}\input{main}"` and then use `perl -wnE 'say $1 if /(?:\*{p.+?\})\s*)\{.+?)\}(?:\s*\.+?\)/' snapshot.dep`

Answer (score 4):

My rather simplistic approach was to search for `\usepackage`, extract the contents and install using the distribution's package manager.

```
cat *.tex | sed -n 's/^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$/tex\(\1.sty\)/p' | paste -sd ' ' -
```

This returns a list of packages with `.sty` and surrounded by `tex()`, e.g. `tex(amsmath.sty) tex(enumitem.sty) tex(graphicx.sty)`. I can pass these straight to `yum`/`dnf` (I'm using Fedora).

```
sudo dnf install $( cat *.tex | sed -n 's/^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$/tex\(\1.sty\)/p' | paste -sd ' ' - )
```

There were a couple of packages I had split over multiple lines that the `sed` expression missed, which I installed manually using `sudo dnf install 'tex(some-package-name.sty)'`.

Hopefully there's a simple `.sty` installing equivalent for `apt-get` on ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you jozxyqk.
I used your command in this form: `cat *.tex | sed -n 's~^[^%]*\\usepackage[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*$~\1.sty~p'|while read file; do tlmgr install $file; done` This work like a charm for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, all too often LaTeX "package" (file) name and CTAN package name are not the same. :/

Comment: @Raphael That's the beauty of the Fedora packaging jozxyqk described -- for example, the Fedora `texlive-hyphen-base` package has all of these `Provides` defined: `tex(dumyhyph.tex)`, `tex(hyphen.tex)`, `tex(hypht1.tex)`, `tex(zerohyph.tex)`. If a user runs `sudo dnf install ...` any of those requirements, they'll get the `texlive-hyphen-base` package installed. Basically, every package has each of its component LaTeX packages broken out into the metadata, so that in Fedora's repos, the latex package name _is_ the same as (well, is mapped to) the distribution package name.

Comment: While I (frequently) rant about how `texlive` is packaged in the repo, I can't fault them for their metadata game. (That being said, the metadata doesn't require that the distribution provides _**six thousand four hundred forty eight** separate `texlive-` packages_ in its package repos. There's such a thing as **too** granular, and when each package is < 30K in size I'm convinced the metadata overhead obliterates any space savings. Plus, the web of interdependencies means you can't _really_ install "just" one specific package; it'll end up pulling in literally ~200 others.)

Comment: And, for those who recommend simply installing all of TeXlive: Some of us have portable devices with no hard drive, where a very large portion of the storage is occupied by system apps that we cannot uninstall (even more, if we use a lot of apps). That does not leave many places to put 5GB.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such functionality builtin as mentioned. However, with some botching one can create a small wrapper that does exactly that.

Simply scanning the packages is often not enough because you don't get the dependencies.

`itex` uses `expect` to catch errors and install the packages on the fly.

https://github.com/dopefishh/itex

With `itex` you only need to install the texlive infrastructure and the script will install the rest.