# Automatic package install in linux?

Tags: packages, installing, linux, updating

In Windows, I run TexWorks, and when I include a package that I do not already have installed, it asks me if I want to install that package.

In linux (Ubuntu), I have tried this in TexWorks, and TexStudio, but it simply results in error, package not found. Is there a way to get such functionality in Linux?  I tried installing texlive, but this did not evidently include that functionality.

Comment: In fact the downloads are managed by the TeX distribution (such as MikTeX) and not by Latex editors. Maybe you need to check your distribution parameters.

Comment: The general recommendation is to do a full texlive install if you can spare the 4.7 GB needed, specially if you're new to any of the tools involved (learning TeX/LaTeX. the operating system, TeX distribution, TeX editor/IDE). If not, check out  [Auto Package download for TeXLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/auto-package-download-for-texlive).

Comment: @alwaysask You don't even have to spare all the 4.7GB.  You can for example omit the `doc` and the `source` tree, which saves you already a lot.

Comment: I don't think it would be a solution for someone new to TeXLive & friends. His next question could be "why TeXstudio (or whatever edior) gives me an error when I click on package doc". My advice is to start with a fire-and-forget solution and *after* you see it working, tweak to suit your needs - it's easier to turn back than not knowing how to go forward. Not much difference between 2 gigs and 5 gigs nowadays anyway. @HenriMenke

Comment: Ive been down-loading the additional packages via my package manager,  and most of the packages work now. (some packages are still downloading, such as texlive-science.

Comment: There is a solution proposed here:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/auto-package-download-for-texlive

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality builtin as mentioned. However, with some botching one can create a small wrapper that does exactly that.

For example, `itex` uses `expect` to catch errors.

https://github.com/dopefishh/itex