# Is there a package manager for latex that allows you to specify and install just the dependencies?

Tags: packages, continuous-integration

I was wondering if there's anything in the LaTeX world that's similar to npm for JS and pipenv for Python. I'm setting up Continous Integration on some of my projects and it seems like overkill to:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: MikTeX allows on-the-fly package installation. Not sure about TeXlive. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110533/28557

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270103/35864. One can install TeX live from TUG and choose a very minimal basic installation. Then `tlmgr` can be used to install specific packages.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398830/35864 might also be interesting.

Comment: texlive-full is as its name suggests a full installation but you can start with a more minimal scheme

Comment: https://yihui.name/tinytex/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tectonic](https://tectonic.newton.cx/) sounds like the closest thing youre searching. It works by downloading the required packages on its own (rather than you provide them, so not exactly like a package manager).

I use a [dockerized version](https://github.com/WtfJoke/tectonic-docker) of it in my travis build for github (its also lightweight, about ~75MB initial download).

As @moewe already pointed out in comments, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398831/144248 or the [github-repo](https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf) for more detailed instructions how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

This simple Python script works for me in Fedora Linux: https://gist.github.com/jopereira/a78d06ee2eb72c4a823588a2333bb890

It scans .tex files for \documentclass and \usepackage statements and finds the appropriate TeXlive RPM packages.