# Missing packages in TeXLive

Tags: texlive, cuted

I have a colleague using TeXLive writing a paper for a Wiley journal using class WileyNJD-v2.cls. The 2019 TeXLive distribution was downloaded via Scientific Workplace.

This class requires cuted amongst other things.

My colleague gets an error saying cuted.sty is not found. (If we comment  cuted out of the class, then changepage.sty is reported as missing.) Obviously, cuted is there for a reason.

How can we download cuted (and any other required packages) on the fly, as MikTeX would do?

Comment: texlive does not do on the fly installation `tlmgr install sttools` should install it if it was not installed originally (most people do `tlmgr install --all` disk space is not usually an issue these days.)

Comment: Doesn't SW install the full TeXLive? or just some subset? The full TerXLive will have `sttools`

Comment: Why sttools? Not cuted?

Comment: @JonathanWebley because cuted is a part of a collection of packages called sttools by the same authors, and it was just easier to handle them as a unit instead of individually.

Comment: I'll ask my colleague to try the "all" install.

Comment: @JonathanWebley given that sapce is cheap these days it is a lot easier to just install the full TeXLIve than figuring out how to install extra packages into texlive from the SW interface (I haven't seen a SW installation in a long time, so I don't know if there is an interface in SW to tell texlive or miktex to install a given package).

Comment: For the other question see [installing - Auto Package download for TeXLive - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/auto-package-download-for-texlive)