# How to install the package "slashbox" using tlmgr?

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I'd like to install the package [slashbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/slashbox) to my MacTex/TeXlive installation (on Mac OSX) using `tlmgr`. The package seems to be still available on CTAN, but my attempts to install it, failed:

```
sudo tlmgr install slashbox
sudo tlmgr install /macros/latex/contrib/slashbox
```

with the error message:

> tlmgr: package repository
>   http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
>   package slashbox not present in package repository.

Which repository to I have to use, or is it impossible to install it via `tlmgr`

Comment: It may be due to Li­cense issue , See:`Un­known Sta­tus, No In­for­ma­tion Avail­able`. Simplest procedure would be to download [slashbox.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/slashbox/slashbox.sty) and place it in working folder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only install packages using `tlmgr` if they are part of TeX Live, not simply if they are on CTAN. In this case, the CTAN database entry indicates no license information is available for the package: that will prevent it being part of TeX Live. See for example [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) (and links there) for details of manually installing packages.

Comment: I ran `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`, which gave me `/Users/accountname/Library/texmf`. But this folder does not exist. I created it and added the file `slashbox.sty`, but still it does not work,...

Comment: @Sven You need the TDS structure inside there, so `/Users/accountname/Library/texmf/tex/latex/slashbox/slashbox.sty` is where the file should live. (You don't formally need the `slashbox` folder, but just dumping everything local inside `tex/latex` is not usually encouraged.)