# ! error: (lua): not enough memory

Tags: errors, luatex, texlive, memory, bugs

I have a heavy document that is compiled with LuaLaTeX (TeXLive). On Linux, no problem. On Windows, it stop compiling in the middle of the document with the error:

```
! error:  (lua): not enough memory
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It actually occurs just before the lualatex.exe compiler allocates 2GB of memory.

I have way enough memory on my computer, it occurs with any versions of LuaLaTeX (even the new 1.0.4 version / TeXLive 2017), it occurs on different Windows configurations, there is no special Lua code in the document.

Comment: Do you use any special Lua code that could "eat" your memory? It's hard to tell more without seeing some code...

Comment: @TeXnician: no special Lua code, just lot of fonts loaded and a big document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard LuaLaTeX from TeXLive is only 32-bit on Windows and thus memory limited. Using 64-bit executables instead solves the problem.

Howto: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227731/15659