# Include all *.bib files in one directory to a bibliography

Tags: bibtex, texlive

There are several *.bib files in one directory which I want to add to my bibliography.

I don't want to add them one by one like this:

```
\bibliography{../dir/a,../dir/b,../dir/c}
```

I tried adding the directory to bibtex like this: (see [here](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/bibtex.html))

```
bibtex --include-directory "../dir/
```

resulting in

```
bibtex: unrecognized option '--include-directory=../dir/'
```

This option seems to be specific to mikTeX BibTeX, but I am using TeXLive.

Is there a way to add all *.bib files in ../dir/ to my bibliography?

I am already using TeX, BibTeX and Make, so a solution using those tools is preferred, although any solution is welcome.

Comment: If you want to go ballistic, a scripting language might help you there. `:)` Say, in Ruby: `p = lambda {|q| puts '\\bibliography{'.concat(Dir::glob(q.concat('*.bib')).map!{|x| x[0..-5]}.join(",")).concat('}')}; p.call('../Sandbox/')` gives me `\bibliography{../Sandbox/mybiblio,../Sandbox/test196,../Sandbox/mybiblio2}`. `:)`

Comment: You may want to use biblatex-biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459222

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, in TeX Live `bibtex` looks for local `.bib` files in your local `texmf/bibtex/bib` folder.  So you can put your directory containing the bib files there, or make a symbolic link inside that folder to your directory.  Either one will work.  Then you just use `\bibliography{a,b,c}` for `.bib` file `a.bib`, `b.bib` etc.

Comment: I'd like to add that I had to run tlmgr update --self --all to make bibtex find the new files in texmf-local/bibtex/bib. Maybe there is another way, but this worked for me.

Comment: @mcwise This probably means you didn't put the files into your *local* (i.e. user level) `texmf` but into the system-wide local `texmf` folder. The system-wide folder is in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`; your user level folder is in different places depending on your OS. (To find out what it is you can use the command line `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`). Files in the `texmf-local` folder (but not in TEXMFHOME) require the `mktexlsr` command to be to rebuild their file databases; this is what `tlmgr` did when you updated.  The update itself wasn't actually relevant.

Comment: Right, I was able to follow your steps and actually put the symbolic link in my user level folder :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no built in way to add all files in one directory, something like `\bibliography{*.bib}`.

However, you could set the environment variable `BIBINPUTS` to `./dir:`; then you will be able to use `\bibliography{a,b,c}` to load `./dir/a.bib`, `./dir/b.bib` and so on. You could also set as many paths as you want, something like `./dirA:./dirB:./dirC:`. The colon here is used to separate paths and when used on the beginning or in the end, is used to add the default path.

To set `BIBINPUTS` you could use `env BIBINPUTS='./dir:' pdftex yourfile.tex` in your command line or Makefile.

There is also a `BSTINPUTS` variable to set paths for `.bst` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LuaLatex :

```latex
\begin{luacode*}
function findBibFiles(folder)
    local files = {}
    local lfs = require("lfs")
    if isDir(folder) then
        for file in lfs.dir(folder) do
            if file:match("%.bib$") then
                table.insert(files, folder .. "/" .. file)
            end
        end
    end
    return files
end

function isDir(name)
    if type(name)~="string" then return false end
    local cd = lfs.currentdir()
    local is = lfs.chdir(name) and true or false
    lfs.chdir(cd)
    return is
end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\setbibliographypath}[1]{
    \directlua{
        local files = findBibFiles("#1")
        for _, file in ipairs(files) do
            tex.print("\\addbibresource{" .. file .. "}")
        end
    }
}

\setbibliographypath{directorypath}
```

You can easily adapt it to handle regular expressions.

Comment: Nice answer. But the question was explicitly about BibTeX not `biblatex`. So IMHO you should adapt the answer, to use `\bibliography` (without file extensions) instead of `\addbibresource`.