# How to fix TeX Live's -output-directory clash with filecontents, revtex?

Tags: output

I routinely use `-output-directory=_out` in TeX Live.

Now, I have noticed that this becomes an issue with `revtex4-1`, which generates a `\jobname Notes.bib` (apparently, in that output folder) but does not seem to find it there. I have to manually copy `_out\jobname Notes.bib` back next to the `.tex` file to make a simple document compile without missing footnotes:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{Hello, world!}
\end{document}
```

A very similar situation is this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SomeOne, author = {Some One}, year = {2018}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Text \cite{SomeOne}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Again, `_out/\jobname.bib` is created, but not found until I copy it from the output folder next to the `.tex` file. This cannot be intended.

Is there a generic fix to this, either by having the `-output-directory` not apply to some commands, or by increasing the search path of the `\bibliography` command? Or is this a bug in TeX Live? I do not remember having this problem with MiKTeX, where I used separate auxiliary and output directories.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172685/30810) implies a `bibtex` argument called `--include-directory`, but it [does not seem to exist in TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192917/30810).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting `BIBINPUTS=.;.\_out` fixed the issue; this is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406871/30810). Note that I used semicolons `;` to separate the entries, while the other answer uses colons `:`.

Comment: In TeX Live on Unix systems, using colons or semicolons is the same (for compatibility with Windows that only accepts semicolons). The enviroment variable should be set with `BIBINPUTS="./_out;"` (use the correct quoting for Windows, or no quotes), so also other bib files can be found.