# How to \addbibresource all *.bib files from a directory with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I'm using biblatex with biber under MiKTeX on Windows. I have many `.bib` files in a directory (say `$localtexmf/bibtex/bib`) which I would like to `\addbibresource` all at once. Is there a built-in option for `biber` to do that?

Related: [Include all *.bib files in one directory to a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192917)

Comment: Biblatex's documentation states it clearly, relative to `\addbibresource`: "Also note that the <resource> is a single resource." There is the legacy `\bibliography` which accepts as argument a comma separeted list of bib files. But it seems to me, there is no escape from listing the individual files, so not much is gained by this in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try `biber` 2.13 from the DEV folder on SourceForge. You can now use BSD style globbing with `\addbibresource` like:

```
\addbibresource{bibfile*.bib}
\addbibresource{bibfile?.bib}
\addbibresource(bibfile{1,2}.bib}
```

Answer (score 3):

TeX can not natively query the contents of a directory. So from within TeX you can't get a list of `.bib` files in a directory and loop over them unless you involve shell escape or LuaTeX.

With shell escape you can run `ls` or similar on the directory and then parse the returned list, with LuaTeX you can use Lua to access the file system, see [How to iterate through the name of files in a folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7653/35864). You could then loop over that list and apply `\addbibresource` for each item.

Biber could possibly query the contents of folders, but it has no user-facing interface to allow you to do that at the moment.

I would assume that the number of `.bib` files and their names are fairly stable, so you could compile a list of these files with `\addbibresource` around each and `\input` that list in all of your documents.

Comment: Another thought in similar spirit: An external script that aggregates all the other bib files and whose result can be individually called by `\addbibresource`.

Comment: I am happy to take a biber feature request for this.

Answer (score 3):

I use an external (PowerShell) script to merge all `bib` files in a folder to one.

```
$bibfile = "C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bib\_all.bib"
$bibtemp = "C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bib\_tmp.bib"
rm $bibfile -ErrorAction Ignore
cat "C:\localtexmf\bibtex\bib\*.bib" | sc $bibtemp
Get-Content $bibtemp | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $bibfile
rm $bibtemp -ErrorAction Ignore
```

It is pretty convenient, you can even add this as the first task in your `biber.bat`, so you don't even have to think about it.

Comment: As PLK indicates in [his comment under my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459222/how-to-addbibresource-all-bib-files-from-a-directory-with-biblatex#comment1186617_459279) he might look into implementing something directly on the Biber side if you think it is worth itr and open a feature request https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. I guess the interface on the `biblatex` side would have to be considered, but even though I known nothing about Perl I guess the Biber side should be doable.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/246