# 'beamer.cls' not found in TeXmaker

Tags: beamer, installing, texmaker

This sound very basic to some but I am confused here.

I want to install TeXmaker on my PC (Windows Vista). I downloaded the software from http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Now when I try to compile my small example I am getting this :

[image]

My question is: why am I getting this? Secondly what is MiKTex?

Can someone please summarize the steps that one needs to do for installing TeXmaker on a Windows machine for the first time?

Comment: Texmaker is only an editor, you have to install a TeX distribution (TeXLive or Miktex)

Comment: Do you have MiKTeX installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeXmaker is just some editor. You could use Notepad as well.

The actual work is done by the compiler, which is part of MiKTeX. If you click translate (or what it is called in English), TeXmaker looks for a compiler, finds and runs MiKTeX.

There might be a more accurate answer, but I think this does the job.

So install MiKTeX (choose "install missing packages on demand") and after that TeXmaker. That should work.

Comment: An alternative to Miktex is Texlive http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20037/36296