# MikTex Installation Error - latex/acroflex/examples/afgraph.pdf Windows 10

Tags: errors, miktex, installing

I tried to install the downloaded version of MikTex 2.9 on my HP Demon laptop and I got the following error.

[image: MikTex installation error]

I tried to change the installation folder but no success. Early help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri Hari.

Comment: Do you install as administrator?

Comment: It is necessary to disable the antivirus during installation

Comment: @AndréC bad advise especially seen the answer already provided.

Comment: @albert Why would that be bad advice? Disabling the antivirus is temporary and solves all problems.

Comment: @AndréC Should be done with utmost caution and be sure that during that time period no other activity (browsing etc.) is done. Better would be to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @albert The problem is the detection of a false positive by the antivirus. The only solution is to contact the support of the said antivirus so that they can modify their scan.

Comment: I agree that false positives are should be reported to the support department of the virus scanner software and also to the owner of the original package (maybe he has a problem). Seen the answer from Tim Menapace it looks like that a mirror had some problems, so not sure if it is  a false positive! might also be the mirror that has a real problem. So in general be very very aware of the risks of disabling the virus scanner and when necessary do it as a very last resort.

Comment: @AndréC You checked and verified that this is a false positive and not an actual infection? You are sure that the mirror doesn't contain any other file that has an infection, coming later in the installation process? That advice, to disable the virus scanner, puts the questioners computer at a risk, so I would not recommend it and I would not say "let's keep this solution here on the Internet forever" but rather delete porentially dangerous suggestions.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz French national education computer experts prohibit the installation of MikTeX and TeXlive on school computers because TeX itself is dangerous because it allows third-party programs to run. However, we have installed them on our own computers.
In this case, it is better to use TexLive which is more secure than MikTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20415/138900

Comment: @AndréC That's one more reason to not disable a virus scanner for a TeX installation. If somebody wants to install ransomware on computers of universities and academic people, he could put some bad script into a ctan mirror and once TeX runs it, it could do anything on the computer. I know you want to help with the advice above, still there will be the valid opinion that disabling a virus scanner is dangerous.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz On windows, disabling an antivirus activates the native `windows defender` antivirus which does not create a false positive for it.

Comment: @AndréC And not a correct positive, if the file is actually infected. ;-)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz This is not what this security expert who worked on Firefox says: https://robert.ocallahan.org/2017/01/disable-your-antivirus-software-except.html

Comment: @AndréC So some guy writes on the Internet that Windows is the most secure without any 3rd party antivirus software. Nice. It should be emphasized here too, that if you recommend to rely on the windows defender only, the windows OS installation should be very up to date. Anyway, it goes a bit off topic.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Read this test by AVTest Windows Defender is a Top Product : https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/windows-10/june-2019/microsoft-windows-defender-4.18-192315/

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when downloading the MiKTeX from a specific mirror, choosen from inside the Net Installer. My virus scanner prompted me with "afgraph.pdf is a trojan horse". 
Than I downloaded MiKTeX directly from https://miktex.org/download , the Basic Installer and everything was fine.

Comment: Simply disable the antivirus during the installation of `MikTeX`

Comment: @AndréC see my comments with the question.

Comment: @albert i saw, but I don't agree with you.

Comment: @AndréC Hacking and infecting servers happens and is pretty automated by criminals, addressing servers and CMSs with vulnerabilities spreading malware for spam etc. In case of a mirror with infected files, you still recommend to "temporary" disable the virus scanner?