# How to set text background transparency with leaflet?

Tags: backgrounds, transparency, leaflet

I am trying to set a semi-transparent background for some text, so we can see the image behind it. To do so, I am using `tcolorbox`. However, it seems that I can not get it working with the `leaflet` document class.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
width=\textwidth,
arc=2mm,
% auto outer arc,
boxsep=0cm,
toprule=0.5pt,
leftrule=0.5pt,
bottomrule=0.5pt,
rightrule=0.5pt,
colframe=black,
colback=white!25,
breakable,
nobeforeafter,
enhanced jigsaw,
opacityframe=0.1,
opacityback=0.5
}

\AddToBackground{1}{\put(0,415){\includegraphics[width=9.9cm]{example-image-c}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears tcolorbox is incompatible with leaflet.cls.  TikZ works, but even the simplest tcolorbox does nothing.

Comment: You could try flowfram instead of leaflet.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248182/number-of-pages-in-leaflet/248248?r=SearchResults&s=24%7C10.5390#248248

Comment: similar issue here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452459/use-opacity-from-tikz-in-leaflet-documentclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leaflet class empties the shipout hooks and this means that tikz can't add the needed resources to the page. With a current (!) LaTeX you could try to use the new pdfmanagement. It uses a different hook that is not affected by leaflet:

```
\DocumentMetadata{} %load new pdfmanagement, requires current latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
width=\textwidth,
arc=2mm,
% auto outer arc,
boxsep=0cm,
toprule=0.5pt,
leftrule=0.5pt,
bottomrule=0.5pt,
rightrule=0.5pt,
colframe=black,
colback=white!25,
breakable,
nobeforeafter,
enhanced jigsaw,
opacityframe=0.1,
opacityback=0.5
}

\AddToBackground{1}{\put(0,415){\includegraphics[width=9.9cm]{example-image-c}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I compile this?

Comment: @Tom with the newest pdflatex, or with pdflatex-dev,  or with  by first loading pdfmanagement-testphase

Comment: I see. Thank you! I try it successfully on local compile. But not working on overleaf, that's could need some time.

Comment: @Tom On overleaf you could try to load pdfmanagement-testphase and then use \DeclareDocumentMetadata as command (we shortened the name in newer latex). But I'm not sure if all the needed patches are already  there in overleaf.

Comment: It's working. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Tom Were you able to make this working on Overleaf? I had no success on my side.

Comment: @Philippe add this `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass`  command.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!