# which should I install, protext or texlive?

Tags: installing

I am a new member to TUG.  But several years ago I used Latex and liked it very much.
Now I would like to get back into it and not sure whether I should install protext or texlive.

I think I'd like to try it with Lyx so would that make a difference in my choice?

Comment: ProTeXt is MiKTeX plus some extras, so this is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex. In the end, both systems work well, and there is not a significant downside to making the 'wrong' choice. As much as anything, it's about whether you want small + autoinstall or 'everything at once'.

Comment: If you want to use Lyx, then I suggested `TeXLive2019` instead of `Protext` ...

Comment: thanks.  After looking back at the Lyx site, I realized that TexLive was probably the best.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would install texlive from the tug website, not from linux repositories.

texlive seems to be the widest spread distro which has the advantage that whatever problem one encounters a quick google will show the solution somewhere on this site.

Comment: thanks, I have the DVD from TUG.