# Which tex systems compiles large documents the quickest?

Tags: compiling, distributions

Is there any resource that compares compile times for different TeX systems?

Comment: editors just write source files, they do not compile anything.  The tex system is installed separately and is the same whichever editor you use

Comment: In addition to what David said, something that could give you the *illlusion* of a difference: many LaTeX files require multiple compilations. Some editors handle that automatically (hence, longer compilation time), while others do not (shorter compilation time, but incomplete file). Of course, in the end you want the multiple compilations one way or the other, and the total time doesn't depend on the editor.

Comment: ah, in that case, I'll change the question to which tex system compiles the quickest

Comment: There are information scattered somewhere around [compiling - Speeding up LaTeX compilation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top) ■ [texlive - What are the advantages of TeX Live over MiKTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Remove the 'editors' and 'ide' tags. `pdflatex` is faster than both `xelatex` and `lualatex`; that's about all I know.

Comment: almost everyone not on windows will be using texlive, on windows, split between windows and miktex but I doubt it is easy to give general answer to your question, so many other factors affect speed notably disk filesystem, so what comparison do you want, and in what case do you have a realistic choice? On linux you can choose between texlive from tug and texlive from your linux package manager, but very unlikely speed is a factor in the choice

Comment: I'm on a linux machine. Has there been a comparison between texlive / tug / texlive from the linux package manager in terms of speed?

Comment: In terms of versions. Texlive of linux packages could be an older/very older  version, almost as good as the newest version,  but you might not be able to compile some examples of this site  using  newest packages, for instance.